# Python: FastAPI error 422 with POST request when sending JSON data

Tags: javascript, python, axios, python-requests, fastapi

I'm building a simple API to test a database. When I use `GET` request everything works fine, but if I change to `POST`, I get `422 Unprocessable Entity` error.

Here is the FastAPI code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
def main(user):
    return user
```

Then, my request using JavaScript

```js
let axios = require('axios')

data = { 
    user: 'smith' 
}

axios.post('http://localhost:8000', data)
    .then(response => (console.log(response.url)))
```

Also, using Python `requests`:

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
data = {'user': 'Smith'}

response = requests.post(url, json=data)
print(response.text)
```

I also tried to parse as JSON, enconding using `utf-8`, and change the headers, but nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 63):

A response having a `422` (`unprocessable entity`) status code will have a response body that specifies the error message, telling exactly which part of your request is missing or doesn’t match the expected format. The code snippet you povided shows that you are trying to post `JSON` data to an endpoint that is expecting `user` being a `query` parameter, rather than `JSON` payload. Hence, the `422 unprocessable entity` error. Below are given **four different options** on how to define an endpoint to expect `JSON` data.

### Option 1

As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#request-body), when you need to send `JSON` data from a client (let's say, a browser) to your API, you send it as a **request body** (through  a `POST` request). To declare a request body, you can use [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) models.

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    user: str

@app.post('/')
def main(user: User):
    return user
```

### Option 2

If one doesn't want to use Pydantic models, they could also use [**Body** parameters](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body). If a single body parameter is used (as in your example), you can use the special [**Body** parameter *embed*](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#embed-a-single-body-parameter).

```py
from fastapi import Body

@app.post('/')
def main(user: str = Body(..., embed=True)):
    return {'user': user}
```

### Option 3

Another (less recommended) way would be to use a `Dict` type (or simply `dict` in Python 3.9+) to declare a `key:value` pair. However, in this way, you can't use custom validations for various attributes in your expected `JSON`, as you would do with Pydantic models or `Body` fields (e.g., check if an email address is valid, or if a string follows a specific pattern).

```py
from typing import Dict, Any

@app.post('/')
def main(payload: Dict[Any, Any]): 
    return payload
```

In the example above, `payload` could also be defined as `payload: dict[Any, Any]`, or simply `payload: dict`.

### Option 4

If you are confident that the incoming data is a valid `JSON`, you can use [Starlette's `Request` object directly](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/using-request-directly/) to get the request body parsed as `JSON`, using [`await request.json()`](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body). However, with this approach, not only can't you use custom validations for your attributes, but you would also need to define your endpoint with `async def`, since `request.json()` is an `async` method and thus, one needs to `await` it (have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71517830/17865804) for more details on `def` vs `async def`).

```py
from fastapi import Request

@app.post('/')
async def main(request: Request): 
    return await request.json()
```

If you wish, you could also implement some checking on the `Content-Type` request header value, before attempting to parse the data, similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804). However, just because a request says `application/json` in the `Content-Type` header, it doesn't always mean that this is true, or  that the incoming data is a valid `JSON` (i.e., may be missing a curly bracket, have a key that does not have a value, etc). Hence, you could use a `try-except` block when you attempt to parse the data, letting you handle any `JSONDecodeError`, in case there is an issue with the way in which your `JSON` data is formatted.

```py
from fastapi import Request, HTTPException
from json import JSONDecodeError

@app.post('/')
async def main(request: Request):
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    
    if content_type is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='No Content-Type provided')
    elif content_type == 'application/json':
        try:
            return await request.json()
        except JSONDecodeError:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Invalid JSON data')
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Content-Type not supported')
```

If you would like the endpoint accepting **both** specific/pre-defined and arbitrary JSON data, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76131296/17865804) out.

### Test the above options

##### Using Python requests library

Related answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975923/17865804).

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
payload ={'user': 'foo'}
resp = requests.post(url=url, json=payload)
print(resp.json())
```

##### Using JavaScript [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API)

Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804) as well. For examples using `axios`, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73414443/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73096718/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71023536/17865804).

```js
fetch('/', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({'user': 'foo'})
    })
    .then(resp => resp.json()) // or, resp.text(), etc
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data); // handle response data
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 56):

Straight from the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#request-body-path-query-parameters):

> The function parameters will be recognized as follows:
>
> - If the parameter is also declared in the **path**, it will be used as a path parameter.
> - If the parameter is of a **singular type** (like int, float, str, bool, etc) it will be interpreted as a **query** parameter.
> - If the parameter is declared to be of the type of a **Pydantic model**, it will be interpreted as a request **body**."

So to create a POST endpoint that receives a body with a user field you would do something like:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel


app = FastAPI()


class Data(BaseModel):
    user: str


@app.post("/")
def main(data: Data):
    return data
```

Answer (score 49):

In my case, I was calling the python API from different python project like this

```
queryResponse = requests.post(URL, data= query)
```

I was using the data property, I changed it to json, then it worked for me

```
queryResponse = requests.post(URL, json = query)
```

Comment: Thanks!  This got mine working too... but I still wish I knew why passing a dict via data (like the help file instructs) causes the 422 error status code.

Comment: I read that the data field is meant for FormData format... which appears to be a javascript class for passing HTML form data.

https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/issues/3373

Comment: Wow 422 unprocessable entity is a data formating issue after all. The error code and message is not explicit.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using the [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch) API and still getting the **422 Unprocessable Entity**, ensure that you have set the **Content-Type** header:

```js
fetch(someURL, {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  },
  body
}).then(...)
```

This solved the issue in my case. On the server-side I'm using Pydantic models, so if you aren't using those, see the above answers.

Comment: For what it's worth, I didn't start having a problem until I updated fastapi from version 0.63 to 0.70.  I was banging my head against the wall until I saw your response.  I was originally using jquery in which the "type" was set to "json".  I changed my save function to use the fetch api with the Content-type set as you have above and problem solved!

Answer (score 5):

FastAPI is based on **Python type hints** so when you pass a query parameter it accepts **key**:**value** pair you need to declare it somehow.

Even something like this will work

```
from typing import Dict, Any
...
@app.post("/")
def main(user: Dict[Any, Any] = None):
    return user

Out: {"user":"Smith"}
```

But using Pydantic way more effective

```
class User(BaseModel):
    user: str

@app.post("/")
def main(user: User):
    return user

Out: {"user":"Smith"}
```

Answer (score 4):

For POST Requests for taking in the request body, you need to do as follows

Create a Pydantic Base Model User

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    user_name: str


@app.post("/")
def main(user: User):
   return user
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, my FastAPI endpoint is expecting form-data instead of JSON. Thus, the fix is to send form data instead of JSON. (Note: for node-js, FormData is not available and [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data) can be used)

Answer (score 1):

(if not syntax error like above)
There could be many reasons for receiving a response 422 from a post request.

#### One can replicate this by:

- editing your body structure
- changing the type of your body (Send any string)
- changing/removing your header content type

#### How I usually debug this is as follows:

1. If you are using FastAPI, test on the local host using the built-in, '/docs' route, if a post fails there, it's likely a syntax/logic error and not related to your post route. This feature of FastAPI is very helpfully. Note Post requests don't need/expect headers on the UI since it gives you a text place to fill it in.
2. Test is on a variable body endpoint: you can set this up like:

```
@app.post('/test')
async def function(objectName: dict = Body(...)):
```

Send a request with any JSON, if you still receive 422, then move to next.

3. Make sure your header content type is correct, the most common is just:

```
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'};
```

Answer (score 1):

This error seems to be a result of origin hanging up before FastAPI finished.

I was calling FastAPI from Java and it was returning too early.

To fix this error I added usage of `CompletableFuture<String>` and using `HTTPClient.sendAsync` function and then calling `CompletableFuture.get` on the promise.

Answer (score 0):

The issue for me was that my POST's body did not contain all the properties the endpoint was looking for:

**POST**

```json
{
    "gateway": "",
    "nameservers": [],
    "deleteWiFi": true,
    "ssidPassword": ""
}
```

**FastAPI python**

```py
class SubmitWiFi(BaseModel):
    gateway: str
    addresses: list[str]    # missing
    nameservers: list[str]
    deleteWiFi: bool
    ssid: str   # missing
    ssidPassword: str

@app.post("/submitWiFi")
async def submitWiFi(data: SubmitWiFi):
    # my code
```

This is not a very descriptive error and hard to find the cause.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered **- "POST /login HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity** error while working on user authentication with FastAPI. This issue was because of how i was capturing auth data from the client. I'll share the solution and what i was doing wrongly

###### Solution

```py
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordBearer
from fastapi.security import OAuth2PasswordRequestForm
from fastapi import Depends

oauth2_scheme = OAuth2PasswordBearer(tokenUrl="login")

@app.post('/login', response_model=Dict)
def login(
        payload: OAuth2PasswordRequestForm = Depends(),   # <--- here's all that matters
        session: Session = Depends(get_db)
    ):
    ### login logic
```

In my case, instead of using `OAuth2PasswordRequestForm`, i was using a UserScheme that capture `username` and `password` and declared it a Body param on function signature i.e

```py
@app.post('/login', response_model=Dict)
def login(
        payload: UserSchema = Body()
       ....
       ....
)
```

The above isn't entirely wrong. It did work very fine when I was using the login endpoint as is.

[image: Build with FastAPI - authorize buttons]

On attempt to use the Authorize button for authentication which uses the `login` endpoint underhood (as that's what's passed as tokenUrl) that's when i get the **Unprocessable Entity Error**

Hope this helps

### Edit 1 ( adding some more context )

Answer (score 0):

The short answer: the error indicates that the wrong content type is passed.

I started getting these errors from curl when I upgraded FastAPI from *0.61.2* to *0.101.1*. My command was like this:

```bash
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8000/model -d '{"text":"o"}'
```

It turned out that the new FastAPI requires to specify the content type:

```bash
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8000/model -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"text":"o"}'
```