# How to send JSON or Form data to FastAPI backend through Axios JavaScript HTTP request?

Tags: python, http, post, axios, fastapi

I have a FastAPI backend configured as such:

```py
@app.post("/engines/completions")
async def read_completions(
    # engine_id:str,
    prompt: Optional[str] = None,
    max_tokens: Optional[int] = 16,
    temperature: Optional[float] = 1.0,
    top_p: Optional[float] = 1.0,
    top_k: Optional[int] = 40,
    n: Optional[int] = 1,
    stream: Optional[bool] = False,
    logprobs: Optional[int] = None,
    echo: Optional[bool] = False,
    stop: Optional[list] = None,
    presence_penalty: Optional[float] = 0.0001,
    frequency_penalty: Optional[float] = 0.0001,
    best_of: Optional[int] = 1,
    recursive_depth: Optional[int] = 0,
    recursive_refresh: Optional[int] = 0,
    logit_bias: Optional[Dict[str, float]] = None,
):
```

and an Axios request configured like this:

```js
let stop = "stuff";
let prompt ="test";
let url = "http://localhost:8000/engines/completions";
const options = {
  method: "POST",
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json"},
  timeout: 2000000,
  body: {stop, prompt},
  url,
};
axios(options)
```

My request goes through without getting a `442` error, but `prompt` and `stop` attributes would result in `None` in my `read_completions` function. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

> My request will go through without a 442

Your request goes through, as all parameters are defined as optional. Thus, not receiving these parameters, the server won't complain.

> but prompt and stop will evaluate as None in my read_completions
> function.

They are both `None` (null), as the server never received any values for them. Your endpoint expects these parameters being [`Query`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/) parameters, however, your client sends (or actually, attempts to send) body parameters.

### Option 1 - Send JSON data

Adjust your endpoint to expect `JSON` (body) parameters. In FastAPI, you could do that using either [`Body`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body) parameters or [`Pydantic`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) models. The example below uses the latter.

```python
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional, List

class Item(BaseModel):
    prompt: str = None
    stop: Optional[List[str]] = None

@app.post("/engines/completions")
def read_completions(item: Item):
    return {"prompt": item.prompt, "stop list": item.stop}
```

Finally, the client side should look like the below:

```javascript
function uploadJSONdata() {
    axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/engines/completions',
            data: JSON.stringify({"prompt": "test", "stop": ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E']}),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

### Option 2 - Send Form data

Adjust your endpoint to expect [`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) data. Also, if you need to define a parameter as a `List`, please have a look at [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/python-types/#list) on how to do that properly.

```python
from typing import Optional, List

@app.post("/engines/completions")
def read_completions(
    prompt: Optional[str] = Form(None),
    stop: Optional[List[str]] = Form(None)
):
    return {"prompt": prompt, "stop list": stop}
```

Then, your client side should look like this:

```javascript
function uploadFormData() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    var alphaArray = ['A', 'B', 'C','D','E'];
    for (var i = 0; i < alphaArray.length; i++) {
        formData.append('stop', alphaArray [i]);
    }
    formData.append("prompt", "test");
    axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/engines/completions',
            data: formData,
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `data` instead of `body` on your axios' options.

See [Request Config on axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/req_config),