# How to send JSON data from Nuxt Axios to a FastAPI backend through a POST request?

Tags: vue.js, axios, nuxt.js, fastapi

I'm trying to send user data from Nuxt.js using Axios via a `POST` request. The data is already provided via a Javascript cdn function that returns an object with `user` parameters, so I wouldn't want to use a `form` since I'm forwarding the `user` data I received as `JSON`.

I wanted to know if the method I'm using is the right way of doing this? I need to send the `user` information in order to send a query in the backend to an external API (requiring a token from both the front and the back end, e.g., user token and app token).

Here is my current iteration:

```js
    <script>
export default {
    head (){
        return {
            __dangerouslyDisableSanitizers: ['script'],
            script: [
                {
                    hid: 'platform-api',
                    src: "https://cdn-sample.app.com/api",
                    type: 'text/javascript',
                    defer: true
                },
            ]
        }
    },
    computed: {
        // Change user token parameter according to docs
        // Add Neccessary parameters
        auth_token: {
            get(){
               let userdata = getPlatformContext();
               this.$store.state.user.auth_token = userdata.auth_token;
               return this.$store.state.user.auth_token;
            },
            set(value){
                    this.$store.commit("item/storeAuthToken", value)
                }
        },
        // Additional parameters omitted as they extract each parameter in the same way
        // as above.
    methods: {
        // I tried to test it by sending just the user token by clicking a button
        async sendUserToken(auth_token) {
            await this.$axios.post(this.$config.baseURL, user.auth_token);
        },
        // Then i wanted instead to try and send the whole json dict of user data to 
        // backend and sort the data over in fastapi according to what i need.
        async sendUserData(user) {
            await this.$axios.post(this.$config.baseURL, user);
        }
        
    },
    
}

</script>
```

So, if I wanted to send the user data as a `POST` request in `JSON` format, not as a `form`, what would be the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is an example on how to send `JSON` data using Axios to a FastAPI backend. The data should be send as a stringified `JSON`. One can do that using the [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) function, which is used to convert a JavaScript object to a JSON string. Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71023536/17865804) (Option 2) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) (Methods 3 & 4).

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request, Body
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

class User(BaseModel):
    username: str
    address: str
    
@app.get("/")
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
  
@app.post("/submit")
def main(user: User):
    return user
```

Note: If one wouldn't like using Pydantic models for posting JSON data, they could instead use `Body` fields, as described in the documentation [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body) and [here](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/). If a single `Body` parameter is expected by the endpoint, one should use the special [`Body` parameter *embed*](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#embed-a-single-body-parameter), as demonstrated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73091485/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) answer.

templates/**index.html**

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.27.2/axios.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function uploadJSONdata() {
    axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: '/submit',
            data: JSON.stringify({"username": "some name", "address": "some address"}),
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = JSON.stringify(response.data);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });
}
</script>
<p id="p1"></p>
<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="uploadJSONdata()">
```

Above is the client side (frontend), which uses Axios to POST the JSON data. Similar approach to the above should be used with the JavaScript framework/library (i.e., Nuxt.js) you are using. For example:

```js
this.$axios.post('/submit', {
    username: 'some name',
    address: 'some address'
  })
  .then(function (response) {
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figure out how to implement this. I've decided to store state of a function with the required info and then post the user info to backend.