# Getting a 422 error response when calling FastAPI backend with a GET request using Axios HTTP Client

Tags: javascript, python, axios, vuejs3, fastapi

I'm trying to make a `GET` request from my Vue3 client (using `axios` JavaScript HTTP client) to a FastAPI server and I´m getting a `422` error response. As I understand, this kind of error messages are related to a bad input.

This is the vue3 code:

```js
import { authToken } from "../main.js"

export default {
  ...
  mounted() {
    const response = axios.get('/checkIsLogged', authToken);
    console.log("authToken" + authToken)
    this.isLoggedIn = response
    console.log("isLoggedin", response)
    if (response) {
      this.title3 = "Mi perfil"
    } else {
      this.title1 = "Sign in"
    }
  },
```

where "authToken"

```
export const authToken = ""

export const setAuthToken = (token) => {
    authToken = token
}
```

On the other side, in FastAPI, the method is:

```py
@empresa.get("/checkIsLogged", response_model=bool)
def is_token_expired(authToken: str):
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(authToken, SECRET_KEY, algorithms=[ALGORITHM])
        expiration_timestamp = payload.get("exp")
        if expiration_timestamp is None:
            return True 
        expiration_datetime = datetime.fromtimestamp(expiration_timestamp)
        current_datetime = datetime.now()
        if current_datetime >= expiration_datetime:
            return True  
        return False 
    except JWTError:
        return False
```

What I´m doing wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `const authToken` can't be changed, it's a `const`ant - but since you never call `setAuthToken` you won't get an error

Comment: @NicoteOol You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) helpful as well

Answer (score 0):

can you print `console.log("authToken" + authToken`) before calling the fastpi api.
Is there a valid value in authToken field?

Method below expects a valid string, and will throw 422 error in case of invalid input.

```
is_token_expired(authToken: str):
```

Also console log the `response.json()` to see exact error. Most likely some pydantic error is being generated

You can also try calling the API with postman

Answer (score 0):

The [`axios.get()`](https://github.com/axios/axios#axiosgeturl-config) method takes a request `config` as the second parameter, **not** query string parameters directly. Hence, your `GET` request should look something like this:

#### Client side

```js
axios.get('/check', {
  params: {
    authToken: authToken
  }
});
```

##### Server side

```py
@app.get("/check")
def is_token_expired(authToken: str):
    pass
```

For more details on `422` error responses, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), which explains the error message and demonstrates how to send a `POST` request with JSON data in the body to a FastAPI backend, using either JavaScript or Python on client side.