# Axios Error 422 (Unprocessable Entity) - Requesting to Send Email Verification Code via POST request (FastAPI backend, React front end)

Tags: python, reactjs, http, axios, fastapi

Trying to verify an email - by sending a POST request via Axios to a FastAPI backend but I'm getting a 422 error (Unprocessable Entity).

I have a Send Verification button, a Verify Code button, and input textboxes for email and verification code. Each button calls on a function via onClick. The Send Verification button calls on the `handleEmailVerify` function to request for email verification. The Verify Code button calls on the `handleVerifyCode` function to verify if the code typed in the input textbox is the same as the one sent to their email.

I'm new to Axios, am I doing something wrong?

This is my React code.

```
    // axios post request for sending email verification
    const sendVerificationCode = (email) => {
      const requestVerificationUrl = '/signup/request-verification';
      const request = axios.post(requestVerificationUrl, { email });
      return request;
    }

    // axios post request for verifying if code is correct
    const verifyCode = (email, code) => {
      const verifyUrl = '/signup/verify';
      const request = axios.post(verifyUrl, { email, code });
      return request;
    };

    // verify email by sending code
    const handleEmailVerify = () => {
      sendVerificationCode(email)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('Verification code sent successfully:', response.data);
        setSentVerification(true);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Error sending verification code:', error);
      });
    }

    // verify if code is correct
    const handleVerifyCode = () => {
      verifyCode(email, code)
        .then((response) => {
          console.log('Code verification successful:', response.data);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.error('Code verification failed:', error);
        });
      console.log(email);
      console.log(code);
```

Here are the errors I'm getting on the front end. (This is after I've input my email and pressed the Send Verification button)
[POST Request Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDelM.png)
[Axios Error 422](https://i.stack.imgur.com/56oIL.png)

For reference, here is the POST request written in the FastAPI backend (not written by me).

```
@router.post("/")
def signup_post(data: SignupData) -> Dict[str, str]:
    db = SessionLocal()
    temp_user = db.query(EmailCodeCheck).filter(EmailCodeCheck.email == data.email).first()
    if temp_user is None or not temp_user.is_verified:
        db.close()
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Email not verified")
    
    # if not registered -> signup 0
    # save new data to db
    hashed_password = hash_password.create_hash(data.password)
    new_consultant = Consultant(
        email=data.email,
        hashed_password=hashed_password,
        name=data.name,
        phone=data.phone,
        birthday=data.birthday
    )
    db.add(new_consultant)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(new_consultant)
    db.close()
    return {"message": "New Consultant Registration Complete."}
```

These are the sample curl commands and request urls showed in the Swagger API docs.

For requesting email verification (`/signup/request-verification`)

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/signup/request-verification?email={sample_email}' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -d ''
```

```
http://localhost:8000/signup/request-verification?email={sample_email}
```

For verifying code sent to email (`/signup/verify`)

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8000/signup/verify?email={sample_email}&code={verification_code}' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -d ''
```

```
http://localhost:8000/signup/verify?email={sample_email}&code={verification_code}
```

### Expected Result

- When 'Send Verification' button is pressed
  -- verification code is sent to email (received via input textbox) with following response

```
{
  "message": "Verification code sent to your email"
}
```

- When 'Verify Code' button is pressed
  -- verify if the code written on another input textbox is the same as the one sent to email and return the following success response

```
{
  "message": "Email has been verified."
}
```

Comment: In addition to the link provided above, please have a lookt at the following answers: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73096718/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71023536/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833951/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77068581/17865804)