# Python: FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity error

Tags: python, fastapi

When I use `GET` request to send data to the server it works fine, but when use `POST` request it throws "422 Unprocessable Entity" error.

This is my Ajax request code:

```js
var newName = "Bhanuka"; 
//do your own request an handle the results
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  url: "/names/",
  data: {d:newName},
  dataType: 'json', 
  success: function(data){ 
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

and this is my FastAPI server side code:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request,Body
from pydantic import BaseModel

from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
app = FastAPI()

templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

@app.get("/items/{id}")
async def read_item(request: Request, id: str):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("item.html", {"request": request, "id": id})

@app.post("/names/")
async def create_item(d:str):
    return d

@app.get("/items11/{item_id}")
def read_item22(item_id: int, q: str ):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

Comment: Please post the complete traceback.

Comment: i have send the variable called "newName " to server side using post request but it shows error called "Unprocessable Entity", but when i use GET request in ajax it works fine response will be appear in console.log that i mentioned in ajax request

Answer (score 2):

It is because the data you are sending is json.
and the POST request api is expecting str.

If the formats doesn't match during the api calls, it raises the Unprocessable Entity error.

You can deal it using

1. requests
2. pydantic

Well, coming to the first case,
1.Request:
you can use request with curl

> curl -i -d "param1=value1&param2=value2" http://localhost:8000/check

to the below code
for example:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder

app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/check')
async def check(request: Request):
    da = await request.form()
    da = jsonable_encoder(da)
    print(da)
    return da
```

2. Pydantics as mentioned in @kamal's answer

Answer (score 1):

A function parameters can be defined as in 3 types like path , singular types and model.  Here you call the method using a `JSON` body and therefore it is likely a `model` parameter. Therefore in your code , define your input parameter as a `model` parameter.

Example -

```
from pydantic import BaseModel 
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

class Data(BaseModel):
    user: str

@app.post("/names/") 
def main(input: Data):
    return input
```

Then you can call this as

```
  $.ajax({
         type: "post",
         url: "/names/",
         data: "{'user':'kamal'}",
         contentType: "application/json",  
         dataType: 'json', 
         success: function(data)
         { console.log(data); 

         }});
```

Answer (score 1):

There was this trouble on me a few days ago.

I solved that with an article, [reference](https://www.fastapitutorial.com/blog/fastapi-jinja-create-job-post/).
So; while get, delete etc. methods working good, post method dont!
I've wrote Form class for parsing FormData coming from fastapi>Request.

```html
class Form:
    def __init__(self, form: FormData, model: BaseModel):
        for k, v in form.items():
            if k[0].isdigit():
                k = f"_{k}"
            setattr(model, str(k), v)
        self.form = model
```

Then I've modified my own decorator as like that:

```
@app.post("/login")
async def check_login(request: Request):
    form = await request.form()
    model: LoginModel = Form(form, LoginModel).form
```

Then I can access the posted data, `model.name` etc.

Answer (score 0):

In short, the endpoint (`/names/`) in your API—in the way that is defined—expects a string **query** parameter `d`, but your client (Ajax request) sends `JSON` payload. Hence, the `422 Unprocessable Entity` error. To receive the data in `JSON` format, one needs to create a [Pydantic BaseModel](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) as follows:

**server side**

```
class Data(BaseModel):
    name: str
    
@app.post("/names/") 
def create_item(data: Data):
    recv_data = data.dict()
    return recv_data['name']
```

Alternatively, one could use the `Body(...)` field—if only a single body parameter is required, use [Body(..., embed=True)](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#embed-a-single-body-parameter) instead, as shown below:

```
@app.post("/names/") 
def create_item(name: str = Body(..., embed=True)):
    return name
```

The client should then look like this (no matter which of the above you use):

**client side**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    url: "/names/",
    data: '{"name": "Bhanuka"}',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

Please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) for more details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

The `422 Unprocessable Entity` error because of `ContentType` is incorrect. The FastAPI need `ContentType = application/json` to parse request body.

But the default **ContentType** for **$.ajax** is `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. For detail [link](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

> contentType (default: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8')
> Type: Boolean or String
> When sending data to the server, use this content type. Default is "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8", which is fine for most cases. If you explicitly pass in a content-type to $.ajax(), then it is always sent to the server (even if no data is sent). As of jQuery 1.6 you can pass false to tell jQuery to not set any content type header. Note: The W3C XMLHttpRequest specification dictates that the charset is always UTF-8; specifying another charset will not force the browser to change the encoding. Note: For cross-domain requests, setting the content type to anything other than application/x-www-form-urlencoded, multipart/form-data, or text/plain will trigger the browser to send a preflight OPTIONS request to the server.

So, you should set ContentType Header for the request as below:

```
var newName = "Bhanuka"; 
//do your own request an handle the results
$.ajax({
   type: "post",
   url: "/names/",
   data: {d:newName},
   dataType: 'json',
   contentType: 'application/json',
   success: function(data){ 
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```