# getting error while using fastapi and html

Tags: python, html, fastapi

import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from predict import predicts
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
import numpy as np
import pickle
import pandas as pd
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request

app=FastAPI()

pickle_in=open("classi.pkl","rb")
classi=pickle.load(pickle_in)

app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')

@app.get('/',response_class=HTMLResponse)
def main(request: Request):
return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})

@app.post('/predict',response_class=HTMLResponse)

async def predict_packet(request: Request,data:predicts):
data=data.dict()
print(data)
x=data['x']
lamda=data['lamda']
congestion=data['congestion']
codec=data['codec']

```
result=classi.predict([[x,lamda,congestion,codec]])
prediction=int(result[0])
```

## return (prediction)

```
return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', context={'request' :request, 'prediction_message': "Your Flight price is Rs. {}".format(prediction)})
```

if **name**=='_*main*':
uvicorn.run(app,host='127.0.0.1',port=8000)

this is in app.py

---

from pydantic import BaseModel

class predicts(BaseModel):
x: int
lamda: int
congestion: int
codec: int

this is in base model

---

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oop2D.png)
error: 127.0.0.1:63857 - "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

want to get the output

Comment: In addition to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) (provided in the link above), you might find the following helpful as well: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70833951/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971004/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70771526/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73420972/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71874694/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846619/17865804).