# How to read body as any valid json?

Tags: json, fastapi, pydantic

I haven't found the docs for that use case. How can I get the request body, ensure it's a valid JSON (**any valid JSON**, including numbers, string, booleans, and nulls, not only objects and arrays) and get the actual JSON.
Using Pydantic forces the JSON to have a specific structure.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804).

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can find nearly everything inside the `Request` object

You are able to get request body with `request.json()`, which will give you the parsed JSON as dictionary.

```
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI

@app.post("/dummypath")
async def get_body(request: Request):
    return await request.json()
```

If you want access the body as string, you can use `request.body()`

Comment: In the `edit` history of this answer it seems that `request.body()` has been replaced by `request.json()` only inside the code block :-)

Comment: how would you make a request to this api from postman ?

Comment: I make a request with form-data selected in the body and get this error "ValueError: [TypeError("'coroutine' object is not iterable"), TypeError('vars() argument must have __dict__ attribute')]"

Comment: Parsed JSON could be a number of different types, not just a dictionary.

Comment: I am trying to access the body for error logging. when I try to access the body with request.body() from a logger, I get "<coroutine object Request.body at 0xram-address>" instead of the body as a string.

Comment: Use `await` if you are getting coroutine object. That means that file descriptor is still waiting.

Comment: Why the  public method `json` from the class or module `Request` is a `coroutine`?, I should read the FastAPI docs.

Comment: I am using this code, without the async clause, but I still get a coroutine. How is it possible?

Comment: It is so simple. If you are getting coroutine you are not using `await`.

Comment: @ChristianSicari Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659178/17865804), if you would like to get the raw `body` or JSON (using `.json()`, which actually returns a `dict` object, as shown [here](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/88e9fc1411f6bd79131afa4a7d2f4dc576c8bf04/starlette/requests.py#L239)) in an endpoint defined with normal `def` instead of `async def`.

Comment: @parashuram the other highly voted answer which uses Body(...) fixes this issue for me

Answer (score 69):

The accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64379772/7732200) is valid as well, but FastAPI provides a built-in way to do that - check the [Singular values in body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#singular-values-in-body) section in docs.

A parameter with the default `Body` gets all the payload that doesn't match passed Pydantic-typed parameters (the whole payload in our case) and converts it to the appropriate Python type. In case of invalid JSON, a standard validation error would be produced.

```
from typing import Any
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI

app = FastAPI()


@app.post('/test')
async def update_item(
        payload: Any = Body(None)
):
    return payload
```

**UPD:** Note on first Body positional argument (default) - None here makes request body optional, `...` (Ellipsis) - marks it as required (passing nothing will actually keep it required). Read more in [the Required with Ellipsis docs section](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/?h=...#required-with-ellipsis)

Also, this solution works for JSON containing only `null`, `true`, `false`, any string, any number.

Comment: `dict = Body()` for the win. This simple line has eluded me for far too long.

Comment: @zelusp I don't know why `request.json()` is recommended and used so often alongside with the regular arg typing stuff. To my mind `Body()` is the most natural way for FastAPI unless you need to deal with a complex body processing or so

Comment: This is undeniably the correct way to do this and should be the accepted answer.

Comment: why use `dict`?

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt this accepts `null`, `true`, `false`, any string, any number, and arrays.

Comment: @caeus it actually can consume arrays. Thanks for heads up, slightly corrected my answer to reflect that in type hint, but anyway it would work. `null`, `true`, `false`, any string, any number - those alone can't be a valid JSON, so it shouldn't accept them

Comment: `null` is a valid json, `true` is a valid json `"Hello world!"` is a valid json, `12345.67` is a valid json. It's not usual to see them at the root of the whole json, but they're as valid as an object or an array. And the question actually states that

Comment: @caeus my bad, checked the standards, you're right. However, this approach still fits, corrected again

Comment: I still wonder; why isn't `Any` just enough? Why the `Any = Body(None)` ?

Comment: @CutePoison I suppose it's a way for FastAPI to tell the full body from regular query params

Answer (score 23):

*If you are confident that the incoming data is **"a valid JSON"***, you can create a simple *type annotation* structure to receive the arbitrary JSON data.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Any, Dict, AnyStr, List, Union

app = FastAPI()

JSONObject = Dict[AnyStr, Any]
JSONArray = List[Any]
JSONStructure = Union[JSONArray, JSONObject]


@app.post("/")
async def root(arbitrary_json: JSONStructure = None):
    return {"received_data": arbitrary_json}
```

### Examples

**1. JSON object**

```
curl -X POST "http://0.0.0.0:6022/" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"test_key\":\"test_val\"}"
```

Response:

```
{
  "received_data": {
    "test_key": "test_val"
  }
}
```

**2. JSON array**

```
curl -X POST "http://0.0.0.0:6022/" -H  "accept: application/json" -H  "Content-Type: application/json" -d "[\"foo\",\"bar\"]"
```

Response:

```
{
  "received_data": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
```

---

If you are not sure about the *content type* of the incoming data, better to parse the *request body*.

It can be done as,

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    return {"received_request_body": await request.body()}
```

The advantage of this method is that the body will contain any kind of data, JSON, form-data, multipart-form-data, etc.

Comment: That is not right, if it is not a valid JSON, Pydantic would throw an error. In addition to that there is nothing called "JSON array" Python parses JSON as Dictionary, so OP 's question is very clear, he wants to get actual JSON which is unparsed one and there is only way to get actual JSON is from `request.body()`.

Comment: @YagizcanDegirmenci Yes, there is something called [**JSON Array**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) which cant not be parsed into a Python ***dict***, but a Python ***list***

Comment: Yes, I'm pretty sure OP did not mean JSON Array in the question.

Comment: OP didn't mention JSON Object too. This answer is meant for those who want to get an *arbitrary JSON( either array or object)* from the request ***not as a string***, as I already mentioned

Comment: Actually, I want ANYTHING that is a valid JSON. Including numbers, booleans, null and strings. Not only objects and arrays.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example to **print** the content of a `Request`, it will print the json body (if it is json parsable) otherwise just print the raw bytes of the body.

```
async def print_request(request):
        print(f'request header       : {dict(request.headers.items())}' )
        print(f'request query params : {dict(request.query_params.items())}')  
        try : 
            print(f'request json         : {await request.json()}')
        except Exception as err:
            # could not parse json
            print(f'request body         : {await request.body()}')
    
    
    @app.post("/printREQUEST")
    async def create_file(request: Request):
        try:
            await print_request(request)
            return {"status": "OK"}
        except Exception as err:
            logging.error(f'could not print REQUEST: {err}')
            return {"status": "ERR"}
```

Answer (score 0):

FastAPI has a [JSON encoder](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/encoder/).

> There are some cases where you might need to convert a data type (like
> a Pydantic model) to something compatible with JSON

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.encoders import jsonable_encoder
from pydantic import BaseModel
import simplejson as json

class SubmitGeneral(BaseModel):
    controllerIPaddress: str
    readerIPaddress: str
    ntpServer: str

@app.post("/submitGeneral")
async def submitGeneral(data: SubmitGeneral):
    data = jsonable_encoder(data)
    #data = json.loads(data.json()) # same as above line
    
    print(f"data = {json.dumps(data)}")

    # you have to access the properties with brackets, not by dot notation
    query = f"update LocalPLC set ControllerIpAddress = '{data['controllerIPaddress']}', ReaderIPAddress = '{data['readerIPaddress']}'"

    return {"status": "OK"}
```

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using BaseModel and want to have a JSON field, you can import Json from pydantic

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel, Json, Field


app = FastAPI()


class MockEndpoint(BaseModel):
    endpoint: str = Field(description="API endpoint to mock")
    response: Json = Field(description="Example response of the endpoint")


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.post("/mock")
async def mock_request(mock_endpoint: MockEndpoint):
    return mock_endpoint
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also another method to get any form of Json as your input

```
@app.post("/dict/")
async def post_dict(data: Dict[str, Any]):
    return data
```

But I guess its not the cleanest way of doing things