# What is the equivalent FastAPI way to do request.json() as in Flask?

Tags: python, json, fastapi, starlette

In Flask, requests from client can be handled as follows.

**For JSON Data:**

`payload = request.get_json()`

**For token arguments:**

`token = request.headers.get('Authorization')`

**For arguments:**

`id = request.args.get('url', None)`

What is the FastAPI way of doing the same?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [FastAPI: how to read body as any valid json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379089/fastapi-how-to-read-body-as-any-valid-json)

Comment: Please have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can call the **`.json()`** method of **`Request`** class as,

```
from json import JSONDecodeError
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    try:
        payload_as_json = await request.json()
        message = "Success"
    except JSONDecodeError:
        payload_as_json = None
        message = "Received data is not a valid JSON"
    return {"message": message, "received_data_as_json": payload_as_json}
```