# How to post JSON data from JavaScript frontend to FastAPI backend?

Tags: python, reactjs, next.js, fastapi

I am trying to pass a value called 'ethAddress' from an input form on the client to FastAPI so that I can use it in a function to generate a matplotlib chart.

I am using fetch to POST the inputted text in Charts.tsx file:

```
   fetch("http://localhost:8000/ethAddress", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(ethAddress),
    }).then(fetchEthAddresses);
```

Then I have my api.py file set up as follows:

```
#imports
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/ethAddress")
async def get_images(background_tasks: BackgroundTasks, ethAddress: str):
    
    image = EthBalanceTracker.get_transactions(ethAddress)
    img_buf = image
    background_tasks.add_task(img_buf.close)
    headers = {'Content-Disposition': 'inline; filename="out.png"'}
    return Response(img_buf.getvalue(), headers=headers, media_type='image/png')


@app.post("/ethAddress")
async def add_ethAddress(ethAddress: str):
    return ethAddress
```

To my understanding, I am passing the 'ethAddress' in the Request Body from the client to the backend using `fetch` `POST` request, where I then have access to the value that has been posted using `@app.post` in FastAPI. I then return that value as a string. Then I am using it in the `GET` route to generate the chart.

I'm getting this error:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59821 - "POST /ethAddress HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59821 - "GET /ethAddress HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

I have also tried switching the fetch method on the client to GET instead of POST. But get the following error:

```
TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you defined `ethAddress` in your endpoint is expected as a query parameter; hence, the `422 Unprocessable Entity` error. As per the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/#query-parameters):

> When you declare other function parameters that are not part of the
> path parameters, they are **automatically** interpreted as "query"
> parameters.

For the parameter to be interpreted as JSON, you need to either:

#### Option 1

[Create a Pydantic model](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/):

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    eth_addr: str

@app.post('/ethAddress')
def add_eth_addr(item: Item):
    return item
```

FastAPI will expect a body like:

```json
{
    "eth_addr": "some addr"
}
```

Using Fetch API:

```js
//...
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({"eth_addr": "some addr"}),
//...
```

#### Option 2

or, use the [`Body`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/) type:

```py
from fastapi import Body

@app.post('/ethAddress')
def add_eth_addr(eth_addr: str = Body()):
    return {'eth_addr': eth_addr}
```

FastAPI will expect a body like:

```json
"some addr"
```

Using Fetch API:

```js
//...
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify("some addr"),
//...
```

#### Option 3

Since you have a [single body parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#embed-a-single-body-parameter), you might want to use the special `Body` parameter `embed`:

```py
from fastapi import Body

@app.post('/ethAddress')
def add_eth_addr(eth_addr: str = Body(embed=True)):
    return {'eth_addr': eth_addr}
```

FastAPI will expect a body like:

```json
{
    "eth_addr": "some addr"
}
```

Using Fetch API:

```js
//...
headers: {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
},
body: JSON.stringify({"eth_addr": "some addr"}),
//...
```

---

Related answers, including JavaScript examples on how to post JSON data as well, can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73096718/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774077/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804).