# FastAPI using Pydantic returns {'detail': [{'loc': ['body', 'dict'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, fastapi, pydantic

Using the code posted below, FastAPI returns a 422 Unprocessable Entity Error when I pass a json dictionary through a post request. I am using a Pydantic BaseModel advised in this documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/#__tabbed_3_1
I've shortened the code snippets so it's easier to read and reproduce.

```py
##CLIENT.PY##
import requests
import json
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'

param1 = 0 
param2 = 'hello world'
param3 = True

data = {"param1":param1,
        "param2":param2,
        "param3":param3,
        }

resp = requests.post(url=url,json=json.dumps(data))
print(resp.json())
```

```py
##MAIN.PY##
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile
from typing import List, Union
import uvicorn
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Params(BaseModel):
    orm_maram1ode=True
    param1: int
    param2: Union[str, None] = None
    param3: Union[bool, None] = None

@app.post("/")
async def API(dict:Params):
    return(dict)

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    uvicorn.run(app='main:app', host='127.0.0.1',port=8000)
```

Thank you in advance!

Ive Found similar posts on Stack Overflow, but unfortunately these solutions are not relevent

Comment: The `json` parameter in `requests` expects a dictionary, not a serialized string: `
resp = requests.post(url=url, json=data)`. In your Pydantic model there's also a missing parameter that you haven't defined anywhere else - `orm_maram1ode` which seems to be in the wrong location (did you mean `class Config: orm_mode = True`?

Comment: See related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804).