# Why there is an error in fastapi while posting data received from weather api?

Tags: python, api, rest, fastapi

I am trying to show weather of a specific city but am unable to execute the program. I am using Fastapi. I also included the BaseModel in the solution but still it is not working. What am I doing wrong?

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, requests
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Data(BaseModel):
    user: str

@app.get("/task1")
def task1(re1: Data):
    re1= requests.get('http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk&appictualappidd=a')
    z = re1.txt
    return z
```

Command to initiate the server:

```bash
uvicorn task:app --host "0.0.0.0" --port 8000 --reload
```

Output in Browser:

```json
{"detail":"Not Found"}
```

I was expecting the returned data from the api on browser's screen but am instead getting an error.

Comment: what url do you type in the browser?

Comment: url was http://localhost:8000

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the proper way to make downstream Https requests inside of Uvicorn/FastAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73721736/what-is-the-proper-way-to-make-downstream-https-requests-inside-of-uvicorn-fasta)

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804), as well as the linked answers included in it, on how to POST JSON data to FastAPI backend using JavaScript in the frontend.

Comment: @Chris this doesn't solve the problem and gives following error.
"INFO:     127.0.0.1:55680 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity"

Following is shown in the browser:
{"detail":[{"loc":["query","user"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}

Answer (score 0):

The problem is defining

```
def task1(re1: Data):
    ...
```

expects you will send **request body** which is no supported in GET requests. Change it to:

```
def task1(user: str):
    ...
```

And type `http://127.0.0.1:8000/?user=my_user` in browser

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did your code actually works without FastApi? DId you try to run your requests.get?

Comment: I tested the api on postman and api is working fine. I don't know what else to look for?