# Python FastAPI pydantic error 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: python, forms, post, fastapi, pydantic

I try to fetch data from HTML form with pyhton Pydantic lib, I'm geeting 422 Error as shown below:

```
{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}
```

**main.py**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Request
from fastapi.responses import HTMLResponse
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from health import Health
import uvicorn
import pickle
import json

import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')

app = FastAPI()
app.mount("/static", StaticFiles(directory="static"), name="static")
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory='templates')




@app.get('/', response_class=HTMLResponse)
def main(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse('index.html', {'request': request})

@app.post('/predict',response_class=HTMLResponse)
def predict(data:Health):
    data = data.dict()
    print(data)
    Age=data['Age']
    hypertension=data['hypertension']
    heart=data['heart']
    married=data['married']
    work=data['work']
    res=data['res']
    glu=data['glu']
    bmi=data['bmi']

    
    return data
```

**Health.py**

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class Health(BaseModel):
    gender:str
    Age:int
    hypertension:str
    heart:str
    married:str
    work:str
    res:str
    glu:float
    bmi:float
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Health care</title>
    <link href="{{ url_for('static', path='/style.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    
    <div class="class">
        <div class="class1">
            <form action="/predict" method="post">
            <div >
                <p id="gen">Gender</p>
                
                    <select name="gender" id="gender">
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="Female">Female</option>
                    </select>
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="ag">Age</p>
                <input type="number" name="Age" placeholder="23" id="age">
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="ht">hypertension</p>
                <select name="hypertension" id="hypertension">
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="hd">heart disease</p>
                <select name="heart" id="heart">
                    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="ma">Married</p>
                <select name="married" id="married">
                    <option value="yes">Yes</option>
                    <option value="No">No</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="wk">Work type</p>
                <select name="work" id="work">
                    <option value="Private">Private</option>
                    <option value="Self employed">Self-employed</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="re">Residence type</p>
                <select name="res" id="res">
                    <option value="rural">Rural</option>
                    <option value="urban">Urban</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="gl">Glucose level</p>
                <input type="type" name="glu" placeholder="90.8" id="glu">
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="bi">BMI</p>
                <input type="type" name="bmi" placeholder="30.1" id="bmi">
            </div>
            <div >
                <p id="so">Smoking status</p>
                <select name="som" id="som">
                    <option value="formal">Formerly Smoked</option>
                    <option value="never">Never Smoked</option>
                    <option value="smokes">Smokes</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="class2">
            <h1 id="heading"><u><b>STROKE</b></u></h1>
            <h3 id="para">A stroke is a medical emergency that occurs when the blood supply to the brain is disrupted, either by a blood clot blocking a blood vessel (ischemic stroke) or by a blood vessel rupturing (hemorrhagic stroke).</h3>
            <h4 id="sym"><u>Stroke Symptoms:</u><br><br>

                Sudden numbness or weakness of the face, arm, or leg, especially on one side of the body.<br>
                Sudden confusion or trouble speaking<br>
                Sudden trouble seeing in one or both eyes.</h4>
                <h4 id="cau"><u>Stroke Causes:</u>
                    <br><br>

                    Ischemic Stroke<br>
                    Hemorrhagic Stroke<br>
                    Transient Ischemic Attack (TIA)
                </h4>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="submit">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="su">        

    </div>
        </form>
</body>

<br>
<h3> lol{{ Age }}</h3>
</html>
```

Comment: You're sending Form POST-data, not a JSON body; you'll have to map the fields by using `Age: int = Form()` for example.

Comment: Please take a look at related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804)