# FastAPI: AssertionError

Tags: fastapi

When i try to start the API with uvicorn, i get following error:

"""AssertionError: Param: nodes can only be a request body, using Body():"""

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.responses import JSONResponse
from typing import List, Dict

app = FastAPI(title="Neo4jAPI")

@app.post("/create_nodes/")
def post(nodes: List[Dict] | None = Header(default=None)):
    #Some Logic
    return JSONResponse(nodes)
```

How do i fix this error?

Comment: You may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By defining `nodes: ... = Header(default=None)`, you tell FastAPI that the values of the `nodes` parameter should be extracted from the request headers.

FastAPI supports headers as single values: e.g. extracting the value of the `User-Agent` header with `user_agent: str = Header()`.
It also supports extracting lists of values from headers, if headers are specified multiple times (see https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/lo/tutorial/header-params/).

However it doesn't support extracting lists of dictionaries from request headers.
How would you even model that in a request header?

What you probably want to do, is extract the nodes from the request body (probably as JSON).
The simple fix for it is just to remove the `= Header(...)` part. If there is just one parameter, FastAPI assumes that this represents the body.

```py
@app.post("/create_nodes/")
def post(nodes: List[Dict] | None):
    return JSONResponse(nodes)
```