# How do I return the request body in a POST request?

Tags: python, rest, fastapi

I'm using fastapi and python. Using a POST method to successfully return data. However, I need to return the request body of my post method to use for some business logic ideally before sending off the query to my database.

How do I go about doing this?

Currently trying `return Request.json` but it's returning a hexedecmial value.

Comment: Can you provide the code for the endpoint you currently have?

Comment: "before sending off the query to my database" - do you want to return a result to the client before communicating with your database after the response has been sent?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you want to return response to the client in POST method before committing it to DB?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned here [FastAPI: how to read body as any valid json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379089/fastapi-how-to-read-body-as-any-valid-json), you simply use the `Request` object:

```
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI

@app.post("/dummypath")
async def get_body(request: Request):
    return await request.json()
```

It return a python dictionary, if the request passed a json formatted body, otherwise check what you request is sending.