# Initializing an empty Pydantic Dynamic model

Tags: python, pydantic

I have data coming into my FastAPI that can take any shape/form and as such I need an empty Pydantic model. I tried creating a dynamic model like this:

```
DynamicModel = create_model('RandomData', random_data=(dict, ...))
```

However it requires the model to follow this structure:

```
{"random_data": { } }
```

What I would like is for the model to accept an empty json dictionary like this: `{ }`

What am I missing?

Comment: why not just use the request body directly?

Comment: as in do not use the pydantic model at all and instead just use the response body?

Comment: yeah, something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379089/how-to-read-body-as-any-valid-json, I am suggesting this because, one of the reasons to use pydantic is for data validation, and in your case that is not what you want

Comment: You are 100% correct. I will go ahead and do this. Thanks so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to read body as any valid json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64379089/how-to-read-body-as-any-valid-json)