# How to post JSON data to FastAPI backend without using Swagger UI?

Tags: python, json, api, post, fastapi

I am trying to do a simple `POST` operation using FastAPI. I have created a basic structure using `BaseModel`, which has only two attributes, namely `name` and `roll`.

```py
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    roll: int

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port=8080, host='0.0.0.0')
```

I would like to post these data using this `POST` operation -
`{"name":"XYZ", "roll":51}`.

I know about the automatic documentation at `http://localhost:8080/docs` provided by Swagger UI (OpenAPI), which we can use to post data. But I wouldn't want to use it. What I would like is to directly post the data using the URL `http://localhost:8080/` and would like to see the result in the browser itself, instead of seeing the result in Swaggger UI.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use a Javascript interface/library such as [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), which allows you to send data in `JSON` format (example is given below). For submiting [`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) data instead, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71665594/17865804), while for posting both `Files` and `Form`/`JSON` data, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804).

For the frontend, you could use [`Jinja2Templates`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) to render and return a `TemplateResponse` that includes your `HTML`/`JS` code, etc. You can use an HTML `form` to submit your data and then have the `form-data` converted into `JSON`, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41431322/how-to-convert-formdata-html5-object-to-json). Otherwise, you could post your `JSON` data directly, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775797/fetch-post-json-data/29823632)—for example, `body: JSON.stringify({name: "foo", roll: 1})`.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    roll: int
    
@app.post("/")
async def create_item(item: Item):
    return item

@app.get("/")
async def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <h1>Post JSON Data</h1>
      <form method="post" id="myForm">
         name : <input type="text" name="name" value="foo">
         roll : <input type="number" name="roll" value="1">
         <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submitForm()">
      </form>
      <div id="responseArea"></div>
      <script>
         function submitForm() {
             var formElement = document.getElementById('myForm');
             var data = new FormData(formElement);
             fetch('/', {
                   method: 'POST',
                   headers: {
                     'Accept': 'application/json',
                     'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                 },
                   body: JSON.stringify(Object.fromEntries(data))
                 })
                 .then(resp => resp.text())  // or, resp.json(), etc.
                 .then(data => {
                   document.getElementById("responseArea").innerHTML = data;
                 })
                 .catch(error => {
                   console.error(error);
                 });
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```