# fastAPI POST route replying "422 Unprocessable Entity" to a request.post() (pure python minimal example)

Tags: python, fastapi

I have this fastAPI POST endpoint (the comments are what I tested according to what I found on the web):

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Any
from fastapi import Body

app = FastAPI()

class Data_schema(BaseModel):
    # jsonObj: str
    # data: Any
    somekey: str


@app.post("/")
async def get_item(payload: Data_schema):
# async def get_item(payload):
# async def get_item(payload: str = Body(..., embed=True)):
    return payload
```

And I test it with:

```
import requests
import json

data = {'somekey': 'somevalue'}

jsonObj = json.dumps(data, indent=4, default=str)
# jsonObj = json.dumps(data)

requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', data=data)
# requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', json=jsonObj)
# requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', json=data)
# requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', json=jsonObj)
```

I cannot get something else than `422 Unprocessable Entity`. I am using python 3.10. Where do I do wrong ?
Thank you

Comment: You can try `return payload.dict()`.

Comment: Please have a look [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) on how to post JSON data to FastAPI backend.

Comment: Thank you, it works now with `requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', json=data)`. It's possible that it was still working but that I didn't see it among the other errors when building this small example.

Comment: For those who wonder how to get the exact error message it's just `response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/', json=data)` `print(response.content)`