# Sending POST request to FastAPI app running on localhost using JavaScript Fetch API

Tags: python, html, json, fastapi, fetch-api

I have a FastAPI application running on my local machine under the URL: `http://localhost:8000`, using the following Python code:

```py
from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware

app = FastAPI()

origins = [
    "*"
    '''
    "http://localhost:8000/add_points/",
    "http://localhost:8000/check_points/",
    "http://localhost:8000/check_item_points/",
    "http://localhost:8000/redeem_points/"
    '''
]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)

users = {"matt": 0}
items = {"ticket": 7}


class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    points: float
    item: str


class AddTransaction(BaseModel):
    name: str
    points: float


class UserPoints(BaseModel):  # anything that extnds this base model is a pyantic model
    name: str
    points: float


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    points: float


# -----Post Requests-----
@app.post("/add_points/")
def add_points(add_transaction: AddTransaction):
    global users
    user_id = add_transaction.name
    points = add_transaction.points
    users[user_id] = users.get(user_id, 0) + points
    return users[user_id]


@app.post("/check_points/")
def check_points(user_points: UserPoints):
    global users
    user_id = user_points.name
    points = user_points.points
    return users[user_id], points


@app.post("/check_item_points/")
def check_item_points(item: Item):
    global items
    item_id = item.name
    points = item.points
    return item[item_id], points


@app.post("/redeem_points/")  # user spends points (they lose points) gain an item
def redeem_points(add_transaction: AddTransaction, user_points: UserPoints, item: Item, user: User):
    global users
    global items
    user_id = add_transaction.name
    user_points = user_points.points
    item_points = item.points
    item_pre = item.name
    item_post = user.item
    if user_points >= item_points:
        user_points == user_points - item_points
        item_post == item_pre
        return users[user_id], users[user_points], users[item_post]
    else:
        return "insufficient funds"


# -----Get Requests-----
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


# -----Put Requests-----
""""
@app.put("/items/{item_id}")
def update_item(item_id: int, item:Item):
    return {"item_name": item.name, "item_id": item_id}
"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

I also have an HTML file with JS script inside that simply sends a `POST` request to `http://localhost:8000/add_points/` upon the click of a button. Here is the code for that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
<br><br><br><span style="text-align: center;"><button id="send">Send Request</button></span>
</body>

<script>
$("#send").on("click", evt => {
    $.post("http://localhost:8000/add_points/",
  {
    name: "string",
    points: 5.0
  },
  function(data, status){
    alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
  });
});
</script>

</html>
```

However, when I try to send the `POST` request I get the following errors in PyCharm:

> INFO:     127.0.0.1:49413 - "OPTIONS /add_points/ HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request

> INFO:     127.0.0.1:49413 - "POST /add_points/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

I understand that at least one of these errors originates from the CORS policy restrictions, however, this project is aimed towards mobile phone users who should **not** have to install any browser extensions for overriding the policy. Any advice as to how to fix these errors would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT UPDATE:

```
const url = new URL('localhost:8000/add_points/');
$("#send").on("click", evt => { fetch(url, 
      { 
        method: 'POST', 
       headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}, 
          body: JSON.stringify({"name":"John", "points":50.0}) 
      }).then().catch((error) => { console.log(error.message); }); });
```

I'm still getting a `400 Bad Request` error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post JSON data from JavaScript frontend to FastAPI backend?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73759718/how-to-post-json-data-from-javascript-frontend-to-fastapi-backend)

Answer (score 1):

If you are accessing the frontend from a [Jinja2 template](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/templates/) or an [`HTMLResponse`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/advanced/custom-response/#html-response)—which seems to be the case, as shown from the `port` that your app is listening on, as well as the `origins` you defined in the [`CORSMiddleware`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/cors/#use-corsmiddleware)—you don't need to have [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) enabled for your application. As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804), two objects have the same origin **only** when the `protocol`, `domain` and `port` all match.

Please note that `localhost` and `127.0.0.1` are considered to be **different** origins. Hence, if you are accessing your fronend from the browser (by typing the URL in the address bar) at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/`, then your asynchronous JS request (using `fetch`, for instance) should use that domain; for example:

```js
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8000/add',...
```

**not**

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8000/add',...
```

and vice versa. You can always use **relative paths** for your `fetch` requests (as shown below), and hence, your app will work regardless of the domain name you used (either `localhost` or `127.0.0.1`) for accessing the frontend from your browser.

#### Working Example:

See related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71741617/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) as well.

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request
from fastapi.templating import Jinja2Templates
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()
templates = Jinja2Templates(directory="templates")

class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    points: float

@app.post("/add")
def add_points(item: Item):
    return item
    
@app.get("/")
def index(request: Request):
    return templates.TemplateResponse("index.html", {"request": request})
```

templates/**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <body>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick="submit()">
      <div id="responseArea"></div>
      <script>
         function submit() {
            fetch('/add', {
                 method: 'POST',
                 headers: {
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                 },
                 body: JSON.stringify({'name': 'John', 'points': 50.0})
              })
              .then(resp => resp.text()) // or, resp.json(), etc.
              .then(data => {
                 document.getElementById("responseArea").innerHTML = data;
              })
              .catch(error => {
                 console.error(error);
              });
         }
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```