# AJAX call with jQuery doesn't act like CURL

Tags: jquery, ajax, curl, fastapi, pydantic

I'm looking to make API call in javascript using AJAX provided by jQuery, but I receive an unprocessable entity error (a pydantic error response from my fastapi server). The strange part is that a curl command DOES work. Its not clear to me why my server can distinguish between the faulty ajax call and the successful curl call.

```bash
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/update' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"gsid":"634ad79ee29c42396b0d4055","ticker":"SPX230317C04200000","security_type":5,"security_subtype":2005,"option_flavor":2,"underlying":{"gsid":"634ad6d1d89536dac325f871","ticker":"SPX"},"denominated_ccy":{"gsid":"634ad6d1d89536dac325f86e","ticker":"USD"},"expiry_date":"2023-03-17","strike":4200,"option_exercise":1,"expiry_series_type":20,"expiry_time_of_day":1,"settlement_type":1,"primary_exchange":"CBO","multiplier":100,"issuer":0,"description":0,"website":0,"as_of_date":"1970-01-01T00:00-05:00","expiry_datetime":"1969-12-31T19:00-05:00","identifiers":[{"id_type":2,"value":""},{"id_type":3,"value":""},{"id_type":4,"value":""},{"id_type":5,"value":""}]}'
```

My API responds to this call correctly, with the following 200 success response:

```json
{
  "success": true,
  "created_security": false,
  "gsid": "634ad79ee29c42396b0d4055",
  "available_versions": [
    "1970-01-01T00:00:00-05:00"
  ],
  "message": "success"
}
```

AJAX call with jQuery

```js
data = {"gsid":"634ad79ee29c42396b0d4055","ticker":"SPX230317C04200000","security_type":5,"security_subtype":2005,"option_flavor":2,"underlying":{"gsid":"634ad6d1d89536dac325f871","ticker":"SPX"},"denominated_ccy":{"gsid":"634ad6d1d89536dac325f86e","ticker":"USD"},"expiry_date":"2023-03-17","strike":4200,"option_exercise":1,"expiry_series_type":20,"expiry_time_of_day":1,"settlement_type":1,"primary_exchange":"CBO","multiplier":100,"issuer":0,"description":0,"website":0,"as_of_date":"1970-01-01T00:00-05:00","expiry_datetime":"1969-12-31T19:00-05:00","identifiers":[{"id_type":2,"value":""},{"id_type":3,"value":""},{"id_type":4,"value":""},{"id_type":5,"value":""}]};
payload = JSON.stringify(data);

$.ajax({
    url: 'http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/update',
    type : "POST",
    dataType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(data){
        console.log('success: '+JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    error: function(data){
        console.log('error: '+JSON.stringify(data));
    },
    data : payload,
});
```

Here I get the following 422 unprocessable entity response from my server:

```json
{"readyState":4,"responseText":"{\"status_code\":10422,\"message\":\"4 validation errors for Request body value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict) body value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict) body value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict) body value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)\",\"data\":null}","responseJSON":{"status_code":10422,"message":"4 validation errors for Request body value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict) body value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict) body value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict) body value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)","data":null},"status":422,"statusText":"Unprocessable Entity"}
```

Comment: Try adding `contentType: "application/json",` to the dict passed to `$.ajax({`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sending a POST request to a local server hosted on FastAPI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74088761/sending-a-post-request-to-a-local-server-hosted-on-fastapi)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT Adding the following to the ajax call worked:

```
contentType: "application/json"
```

Answer proposed by @addjunior

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would ***NEVER*** use jQuery for anything. 
Here is how it would be done in JavaScript.

```
fetch('http://127.0.0.1:8010/api/update', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        'gsid': '634ad79ee29c42396b0d4055',
        'ticker': 'SPX230317C04200000',
        'security_type': 5,
        'security_subtype': 2005,
        'option_flavor': 2,
        'underlying': {
            'gsid': '634ad6d1d89536dac325f871',
            'ticker': 'SPX'
        },
        'denominated_ccy': {
            'gsid': '634ad6d1d89536dac325f86e',
            'ticker': 'USD'
        },
        'expiry_date': '2023-03-17',
        'strike': 4200,
        'option_exercise': 1,
        'expiry_series_type': 20,
        'expiry_time_of_day': 1,
        'settlement_type': 1,
        'primary_exchange': 'CBO',
        'multiplier': 100,
        'issuer': 0,
        'description': 0,
        'website': 0,
        'as_of_date': '1970-01-01T00:00-05:00',
        'expiry_datetime': '1969-12-31T19:00-05:00',
        'identifiers': [
            {
                'id_type': 2,
                'value': ''
            },
            {
                'id_type': 3,
                'value': ''
            },
            {
                'id_type': 4,
                'value': ''
            },
            {
                'id_type': 5,
                'value': ''
            }
        ]
    })
});
```