# Can't reach RestAPI (FastAPI) from my Flutter web - Cross-Origin Request Blocked

Tags: python, flutter, docker, nginx, fastapi

I have a Linux Server. On that I have two Docker Containers.In the first one I am deploying my Flutter Web and in the other one I am running my RestAPI with FastAPI().

I set both the Docker containers in the same Network, so the communication should work. I also set origins with `origins = ['*']` (Wildcard). I reverse proxy my Flutter web with `nginx` from the Linux server. I also include `*.crt` and `*.key` with nginx to my Flutter Web.

Now, obviously, since my Flutter Web App has `https`, I cant make `http` calls. When I am trying to make a call with `https`, I get the Error (from catch): `"XMLHttpRequest error"`, and in the Browser Console I get:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at https://172.21.0.2:8070/. (Reason: CORS request
> did not succeed). Status code: (null).

(172.21.0.2 is the ip of the Docker and 8070 the port on RestApi running)

I am new to the RestAPI world. I normaly develop only Frontend. But I wanted to give it a try. So I'm sorry if I expressed some things wrong. I am searching since days but cant find a solution to my problem. I would be grateful for any help! (If i missed some information or you need more, feel free to write in the comments, I will update the Question immediately!)

Thank You!

Comment: If an error happens in the API, the CORS headers will not be included - i.e. meaning that any attempt to make the request from the frontend will fail with a CORS error. Your browser will probably not trust self-signed crt/keys either - what happens if you go directly to `https://172.21.0.2:8070/` in your browser? What's the result then? (CORS is only checked when the request is made on behalf of another page). What about using `curl` to call the endpoint?

Comment: Same happened for me. For me it was during calling get method. So i changed to post method.It worked for me.

Comment: @MatsLindh ty for your response. I couldnt answer earlier. Since all of them running on the ubuntu server edition, I cant check in the Browser. I know that I can reach the Docker. I also checked the Network Monitor on Firefox and can see "NS_ERROR_NET_TIMEOUT". I deploy my API with with uvicorn through the Docker with : "FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9" .

Comment: You may find [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71805329/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75048778/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73963905/17865804) helpful

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved my problem. If anyone face the same problem in the future, here is the answer.
My mistake was to call the server with `http`/`https`, while in the same (Docker) Network. So I changed:

```
final Uri tokenUri = Uri.https(urlList[index]['url']!, '');
```

to

```
final Uri tokenUri = Uri.parse('${urlList[index]['url']!}/');
```

One week of search for such an easy solution.