# Values not getting passed from React JS dropdown to Fast API backend

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fastapi

I am pretty novice to front-end tasks and I am trying to add few dropdowns to my exisitng `React` JS code. What I want it is that at event execution, pass the selected dropdown values of these along with exisitng paramters to my `FastAPI` backend and somehow it comes up empty or undefined.

Here's my JS code:

```
import "./App.css";
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  /* few other const variables */
  const [isDropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const [validationError, setValidationError] = useState(false);
  let text = "";

  const [MultiOption1, setMultiOption1] = useState('');
  const [MultiOption2, setMultiOption2] = useState('');

  const OptionChange1 = (event) => {
    setMultiOption1(event.target.value);
  };

  const OptionChange2 = (event) => {
    setMultiOption2(event.target.value);
  };

function EnterPress(event) {
    if (event.target.value) {
      setValidationError(false);
      text = event.target.value;
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        display(event.target.value,MultiOption1,MultiOption2);
        event.target.value = "";
      }
    }
    else{
      if (event.keyCode === 13) {
      setValidationError(true);
      }
    }
  }

const submit = async () => {
    text = document.getElementById("text").value;
    if (text) {
      display(text);
      text = "";
      document.getElementById("text").value = "";
    }
    else {
      setValidationError(true);
    }
  };

async function display(text,MultiOption1, MultiOption2) {
    
    let response = ""
    await fetch(`http://0.0.0.0:80/route?MultiOption1=${MultiOption1}&MultiOption2=${MultiOption2}`,
    {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: ""
    }).then(resp => resp.json()).then(data => {
        console.log("data...", data);
        response = data;
    })
    
  };

return (
  <>

    <div className="divBlock ff">

    <div className="app-container">
      <div className="left-panel">
        <label htmlFor="dropdown1">Dropdown 1:</label>
        <select id="dropdown1" value={MultiOption1} onChange={OptionChange1}>
          <option value="Option1">Option 1</option>
          <option value="Option2">Option 2</option>
          <option value="Option3">Option 3</option>
        </select>
        <label htmlFor="dropdown2">Dropdown 2:</label>
        <select id="dropdown2" value={MultiOption2} onChange={OptionChange2}>
          <option value="OptionA">Option A</option>
          <option value="OptionB">Option B</option>
        </select>
      </div>
      
      <div className="Block">
        /*Additional div elements */

        <div className="text-field" onClick={EnterPress}>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="text"
            className={validationError ? 'errorText' : 'text'}
            onKeyDown={EnterPress}
          />
          
          <button onClick={submit} className="arrowButton">
            <ion-icon className="arrow" name="send"></ion-icon>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div >

   </div>

    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

My Fast API function call looks like this:

```
@app.post("/route")
def ask(MultiOption1: str = None, MultiOption2: str = None):
```

I know the issue is that somewhere I am missing some code or function call or settign the values properly at event trigger, but I am unable to get the values passed properly to my Fast API. It comes as empty string

Comment: You don't need to pass the MultiOption1 and MultiOption2 to the display function because you are already storing them with useState.

Also you are passing  selectedOption1 and selectedOption2 which don't exist.

Partially working: https://codesandbox.io/s/aged-grass-xsh9mh?file=/src/App.js:2899-2905

Comment: @Klian sorry, that was a typo. Its MultiOption1 and 2. Changed now. I was going through the code in the link but couldn't find the difference/change. Can you point where excatly change happens?

Comment: Please have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74106637/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) as well

Comment: @Chris FAST API can run on any host or port I specify as long as its available. Mine is running locally on `http://0.0.0.0:80` which is a valid ip for local. And I have mentioned in my post that I am getting an empty value passed. There is no error, its jsut empty value for the parameters I am passing.

Comment: @Chris yes I saw the links. Its not concerning my issue. My issue is not that I am getting a CORS error or some error. Its just that the two dropdowns I wnat to pass are not getting passed and are coming empty string in my backend. Other parameters or data I am passing is getting passed.

Comment: @user2966197 please check the code I created for you again. The differences are pretty clear. For example, you are not setting default values for MultiOption1 and MultiOption2.