# how do I make API request after deploying uvicorn via fastapi in mylaptop

Tags: python, fastapi

I am new to FastAPI/model deployment, I managed to created a model which can return a result using the FastAPI docs path in my local server/laptop.

My question is, how can i access this model in jupyter notebook?

Trying to relate into other API request such as Foursquare API. How do I wrap a params dictionary

Tried the following however it is not working

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/predict'
params = { 'title' : ['Product Operations Software Engineer (DevOps / SRE)']}

result = requests.post(url, params)

<Response [422]>
result.text
'{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}'
```

**Input**
[image]

**Output**
[image]

My Code

```
from  fastapi import FastAPI
import numpy as np
import dill
import pandas as pd
import uvicorn
import re
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class JobTitle(BaseModel):
    title: list


#load model
with open("logisticmodel", "rb") as to_load:
    logistic_model = dill.load(to_load)

@app.get("/")
def home():
    return 'welcome'

@app.post("/predict")
def predict(request: JobTitle):
    
    X = pd.Series(request.title)
    result = logistic_model.predict(X)
    return {'Type' : list(result) }
```

Comment: Is your server on another device? Then, AFAIK, you can't use `http://127.0.0.1` to refer to it. You'll have to use either external IP, or local network IP (if connected to the same network).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to post JSON data to FastAPI and retrieve the JSON data inside the endpoint?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70975344/how-to-post-json-data-to-fastapi-and-retrieve-the-json-data-inside-the-endpoint)

Comment: Related answers can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code here indicates that your data should be put inside the HTTP request body

```py
@app.post("/predict")
def predict(request: JobTitle):
    ...
```

But when you issue the HTTP request with the `requests` module,
you didn't put anything to your request body.
You should use `json` argument so the data can be put to the right place:

```py
result = requests.post(
    url,
    json={'title': ['Product Operations Software Engineer (DevOps / SRE)']}
)
```

You can check [this](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests) for sending an HTTP request with request body using `requests` module,
and [this](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) for building an API with a request body.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `.dict()` to get the dictionary of BaseModel instance. In your case, `request.dict()`

Also, Define your model like this,

```py
class JobTitle(BaseModel):
    title: List[str]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```py
>>> result = requests.post(url, json=params)
>>> result
<Response [200]>
```