# How to post JSON data to FastAPI and retrieve the JSON data inside the endpoint?

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, streamlit

I would like to pass a JSON object to a FastAPI backend. Here is what I am doing in the frontend app:

```py
data = {'labels': labels, 'sequences': sequences}
response = requests.post(api_url, data = data)
```

Here is how the backend API looks like in FastAPI:

```py
@app.post("/api/zero-shot/")
async def Zero_Shot_Classification(request: Request):
    data = await request.json()
```

However, I am getting this error:

```json
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use the `json` parameter instead (which would change the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`):

```py
payload = {'labels': labels, 'sequences': sequences}
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

not `data` which is used for sending form data with the `Content-Type` being `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default, or `multipart/form-data` if `files` are also included in the request—unless you serialised your JSON first and manually set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71646731/17865804):

```py
payload = {'labels': labels, 'sequences': sequences}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={'Content-Type': 'application/json'})
```

Also, please have a look at the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) on how to benefit from using Pydantic models when sending JSON request bodies, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) for more options and examples on how to define an endpoint expecting JSON data.