# How to make a Post request to an API using Google Colab

Tags: python, python-requests, request, google-colaboratory

I need to make the following POST request using Google Colab:

```
POST https://http.msging.net/commands HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json 
Authorization: Key YOUR_TOKEN 

{ 
"id": "a456-42665544000-0123e4567-e89b-12d3", 
"to": "postmaster@wa.gw.msging.net", 
"method": "get", 
"uri": "lime://wa.gw.msging.net/accounts/+55115555555" 
}
```

I have tried:

```
import requests
import re

YOUR_TOKEN = "mytoken"

data = { 
"id": "a456-42665544000-0123e4567-e89b-12d3", 
"to": "postmaster@wa.gw.msging.net", 
"method": "get", 
"uri": "lime://wa.gw.msging.net/accounts/+55115555555" 
}

headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json", 
  "Authorization": YOUR_TOKEN 
}
response = requests.post('https://http.msging.net/commands', headers=headers, data=data)

print(response)
```

For which I get:

```
<Response [400]>
```

I also tried:

```
import requests
import re

YOUR_TOKEN = "Key cHJvY29ycG9lc3RldGljYWF2YW5jYWRhMTg6cEFBSXFuYTZOR1FFWnpydFltTlo="

data = { 
"id": "a456-42665544000-0123e4567-e89b-12d3", 
"to": "postmaster@wa.gw.msging.net", 
"method": "get", 
"uri": "lime://wa.gw.msging.net/accounts/+55115555555" 
}

headers = {
  "Content-Type": "application/json", 
  "Authorization": YOUR_TOKEN 
}
response = requests.post('https://http.msging.net/commands HTTP/1.1', headers=headers, data=data)

print(response)
```

For which I get:

```
<Response [404]>
```

How do I get this request using Google Colab?

[Here is the documentation](https://help.blip.ai/hc/en-us/articles/4474382664855-How-to-send-WhatsApp-notifications-through-Blip-API), it does not provide examples. Just the requests.

Comment: have you tested your post request work without colab first?

Comment: No, because, even if it works outside Colab, I would not be able to implement it. I am constricted by the use of Colab.

Comment: @user3347814 then it is not colab specific issue, make sure your api call work first with `curl` command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a `400 Bad Request` error, as - although you set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json` - you do not send `JSON`-encoded data.

As per Python requests [documentation](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests), when sending `JSON` data, you need to either use the `data` parameter and pass a `JSON`-encoded string, as well as manually set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`:

```py
payload = {'some': 'data'}
r = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(payload), headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"})
```

or, if you don't want to encode the `dict` yourself, use the `json` parameter, and Python requests will automatically encode it for you, as well as set the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`:

```py
r = requests.post(url, json=payload)
```

You would still need to add your `TOKEN` key to the `Authorization` header, as you already do.

Comment: Given the documentation, could you please provide an example with the specifics of this API?

Comment: The HTTP/1.1 would be included some where or I can just ignore it?