# Content-type is different when sending file to FastAPI backend using cURL than Python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, fastapi

I have API which accepts JSON data and file (`png`).

This is my fastapi code:

```
@app.post("/api/")
async def dummy_file_return(metadata=Body(...),file=File(...)):
  print("content_type is")
  print(file.content_type)
```

When accesing with `curl`.

```
$curl -X POST -F file=@0_for_django_testcase.png -F metadata='{"meta":"test"}' localhost:8008/api/
```

server log shows,

> content_type is
> image/png

I can see `content_type` is guessed automatically and `image/png` is set.

Then, I tried the same thing by `requests` of `python`.

```
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data={"metadata":json.dumps({"meta":"test")},
        files = {
            "file": open('0_for_django_testcase.png','rb')
        },
    )
```

console shows

> content_type is

`content_type` is empty and nothing appears.

Why this difference occurs?

**In either way file upload is successed, however there is difference for content_type.**

I don't set any header for `curl` though, `-F` flag secretly send some headers?

Another trial, I tested these patterns with headers, but both returns `<Response [400]>` error.

```
    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data={"metadata":json.dumps({"meta":"test")},
        files = {
            "file": open('0_for_django_testcase.png','rb')
        },
        headers={
            "Content-Type":"image/png"
        }
    )


    response = requests.post(
        url,
        data={"metadata":json.dumps({"meta":"test")},
        files = {
            "file": open('0_for_django_testcase.png','rb')
        },
        headers={
            "Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"
        }
    )
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: `curl` guesses the mime type for you. See [How does `curl` on the command line determine the MIME type of a file being uploaded?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396385/how-does-curl-on-the-command-line-determine-the-mime-type-of-a-file-being-uplo).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I would suggest having a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), which provides detailed information on how to upload file(s) in FastAPI. Second, you don't seem to be sending `JSON` data along with the file, but rather `Form` data. That is the case when using the `data` argument in `requests`, regardless of defining the parameter with `Body()` in the FastAPI endpoint, as well as using `json.dumps()` to serialise the value of the `metadata` key. You would also need to set the request's `Content-Type` to `application/json`, or simply use the `json` argument instead (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71646731/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975923/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71471293/17865804)). However, since you attempt sending both file and JSON data, it would not work—please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) as to why your approach would not work, as well as how to achieve that. Hence, the example you provided is working simply because you send `Form` data along with the `file`, which is valid for the `multipart/form-data` content type (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804) as well on how to send `multipart/form-data` using Python requests).

As for the file's `content_type` (better known as *media type* in this case, and formerly known as *MIME type*, see MDN's documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Formats/Containers) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)) not being received, this has to do with the `requests` module. In cURL this is [guessed based on filename extension matching](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/396385/how-does-curl-on-the-command-line-determine-the-mime-type-of-a-file-being-uplo) (note that there is a built-in Python module, called [`mimetypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/mimetypes.html), which offers similar capabilities—examples are provided in the last section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73672334/17865804)). In `requests`, however, you could manually set the `content_type` for `files` when sending the request—see the relevant documentation [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file) and [here](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/#requests.request) (have a look at the `files` argument) for more details, as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76437623/17865804). If you would like to avoid that, you could instead use [`httpx`](https://www.python-httpx.org/), which would automatically set the `content_type` for you, and still allow you to manually change it in a similar way to `requests`, if you desire, as described [here](https://www.python-httpx.org/quickstart/#sending-multipart-file-uploads) (related posts using `httpx` in FastAPI that might also be helpful can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73736138/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74239367/17865804)). Both options are provided below.

### Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, File, UploadFile

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        print(f'Content type of file: {file.content_type}')
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()

    return {"message": f"Successfully uploaded {file.filename}"}
```

**test.py** (using `requests`)

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
file = {'file': ('1.png', open('images/1.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')}
r = requests.post(url=url, files=file) 
print(r.json())
```

**test.py** (using `httpx`)

```py
import httpx

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
file = {'file': open('images/1.png', 'rb')}
r = httpx.post(url=url, files=file) 
print(r.json())
```