# How to post JSON data that include unicode characters to FastAPI using Python requests?

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi, pydantic

When a FastAPI endpoint expects a Pydantic model and one is passed with a string it works as expected unless that string contains unicode characters.

First I create an example application for FastAPI with an example model.
`serv.py`

```
from pydantic import BaseModel


class exClass(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(example=1)
    text: str = Field(example="Text example")

app = FastAPI(debug=True)

@app.post("/example")
async def receive_pyd(ex: exClass):
    print(ex)
    return True

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn
    uvicorn.run(app, host="127.0.0.1", port=8000)
```

The client that shows the error in question `client.py`

```
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import requests

class exClass(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(example=1)
    text: str = Field(example="Text example")


ex1 = exClass(id=1, text="working example")
ex2 = exClass(id=2, text="this’ will fail")
ex3 = exClass(id=3, text=" <- also non-working")


r = requests.post(f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/example", data=ex1.model_dump_json())
print(r.text)
r = requests.post(f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/example", data=ex2.model_dump_json())
print(r.text)
r = requests.post(f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/example", data=ex3.model_dump_json())
print(r.text)
```

Output:

```
true
Invalid HTTP request received.
Invalid HTTP request received.
```

When `text` contains unicode characters the result is a 422 Unprocessable Entity. I have tried ex.dict(), model_dump(), and using json instead of data in the requests call. Enabling debugging in FastAPI/starlette bubbles up that the Invalid HTTP request is a JSON decode error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not a problem of Pydantic and FastAPI. You should encode you request data like it's shown below:

```
r = requests.post(
    f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/example", data=ex1.model_dump_json().encode('utf-8')
)
print(r.text)
r = requests.post(
    f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/example", data=ex2.model_dump_json().encode('utf-8')
)
print(r.text)
r = requests.post(
    f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/example", data=ex3.model_dump_json().encode('utf-8')
)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: I completely misunderstood the problem, thanks for setting me straight.

Answer (score 2):

When sending JSON data from Python `requests`, one should use the `json` argument to pass a valid dictionary. Using that argument would set the request's `Content-Type` header to `application/json`. The `data` argument, on the other hand, is used when sending form data, and these data are encoded with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` (that is the default `Content-Type` in `requests`), or `multipart/form-data` (if `files` are included in the request as well).

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71646731/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975923/17865804). You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71471293/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75359262/17865804) helpful as well. To return a FastAPI response with unicode or non-ascii characters, please take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77585366/17865804).

Along with setting the `Content-Type` header to `application/json`, you should use Pydantic's `model_dump()` method (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761451/17865804) for more details)—instead  of `model_dump_json()`—which would convert the model to a dictionary.

### Example

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field
import requests

class Example(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(example=1)
    text: str = Field(example="test")


ex1 = Example(id=1, text="Working")
ex2 = Example(id=2, text="this’ will also work")
ex3 = Example(id=3, text=" <- will also work")


url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/example'
r = requests.post(url, json=ex1.model_dump())
print(r.text)
r = requests.post(url, json=ex2.model_dump())
print(r.text)
r = requests.post(url, json=ex3.model_dump())
print(r.text)
```

Comment: This works in the simplified Example class, but the reason I was using data=exN.model_dump_json() is the actual class contains datetimes and that breaks using json=exN.model_dump() without requiring me to make further updates to the class or function

Comment: In that case, you could use [`model.model_dump()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/serialization/#modelmodel_dump) with the `mode` parameter set to `json`, e.g., `ex1.model_dump(mode='json')` (see the [relevant documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_dump)). This would ensure that the returned dictionary will only contain JSON serializable types. Hence, a `datetime` object would be converted into a `str`, similar to what FastAPI's `jsonable_encoder` does, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73974946/17865804)