# FastAPI and Python requests 422 error problem

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I am trying to use FastAPI for a new application that looks at events in the town I live in.

Here's my FastAPI backend:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from utils import FireBaseConnection
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Data(BaseModel):
    name: str

@app.post("/event")
async def create_events(event: Data):
    return event
```

and here's how I use Python requests to test the API:

```py
import requests
import json

mode = "DEV"
dev_server = "http://127.0.0.1:8000"

with open("data/data.json", "r") as f:
    events = json.load(f)

for event in events: 
    if mode == "DEV":
        requests.post(dev_server + "/event", 
                     headers={"ContentType": "application/json"}, 
                     data={"name": event["name"].encode("utf-8")})
```

I keep getting `422 Unprocessable Entity` errors. Anyone know any fixes?

Comment: Can you try: `requests.post(dev_server + "/event", json={'name': event["name"]})` ?

Comment: I'll write as an answer so you can accept the answer and close the question.

Comment: Please take a look at this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975923/17865804) as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error seems in how do you send the Json data to the server. `requests.get()` has an `json=` parameter, so you don't have to set HTTP headers and encode the payload manually.

Simply call

```
requests.post(dev_server + "/event", json={'name': event["name"]})
```

and `requests` will handle the details for you.