# How to POST a JSON having a single body parameter in FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I have a file called `main.py` in which I put a `POST` call with only one input parameter (integer). Simplified code is given below:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/do_something/")
async def do_something(process_id: int):
    # some code
    return {"process_id": process_id}
```

Now, if I run the code for the test, saved in the file `test_main.py`, that is:

```py
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from main import app

client = TestClient(app)

def test_do_something():
    response = client.post(
        "/do_something/",
        json={
            "process_id": 16
        }
    )
    return response.json()

print(test_do_something())
```

I get:

```json
{'detail': [{'loc': ['query', 'process_id'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}
```

I can't figure out what the mistake is. It is necessary that it remains a `POST` call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error basically says that, the required query parameter `process_id` is missing. The reason is that you send a POST request with request `body`, i.e., JSON payload; however, your endpoint expects a query parameter. To receive the data in JSON format, one needs to [create a Pydantic BaseModel](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/)—as shown below—and send the data from the client in the same way you already do.

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

class Item(BaseModel):
    process_id: int
    
@app.post("/do_something")
def do_something(item: Item):
    return item
```

If, however, you need to pass a [query parameter](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params/), then you create an endpoint in the same way you did, but on client side, you need to add the parameter to the URL itself, as described in the [documentation](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/#extended-testing-file) and as shown below:

```
def test_do_something():
    response = client.post("/do_something?process_id=16")
    return response.json()
```

## Update

Alternatively, you can pass a single body parameter using [`Body(..., embed=True)`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-multiple-params/#embed-a-single-body-parameter), as shown below (for more details and options on how to post JSON data, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804)):

```
@app.post("/do_something")
def do_something(process_id: int = Body(..., embed=True)):
    return process_id
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this without creating a Pydantic model? Normally, if I have multiple parameters, I use, for instance: `async def do_something_else(items: List[Dict], process_id: int = Body(...))` in the definition and `client.post("/do_something_else/", json={"process_id": ..., "items": [{...}, {...}]})` for the call.

Comment: But `Body(...)` doesn't work if I have only one numeric parameter, as in the example in my question.