# How to POST a single parameter as JSON in FastAPI?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, fastapi

I have a working model using transformers `pipeline`  and I want to use it with FastAPI to send `post` requisitions and get the response.

The model works this way:

```
#Loading the model
classifier = pipeline(path_to_model)

#Making predictions:
classifier(txt)
```

The output is a `list` of `dicts`.

My code is:

```py
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/predictions")
def extract_predictions(text):
    text = text.lower()
    out=classifier(text)
    return {
            "text_message": text, 
            "predictions": out
           }
```

I can get predictions if I use `localhost:8000/docs`, but when I use postman or insominia and body(JSON) `{"text":"any string"}`  I get `"field_required"`

The model takes a string as an input and my postman request uses a JSON body. How can I update model to get the input as JSON?

Comment: You specify a `response_model=Out`, which you don't seem you have defined in your API; hence, the error `name 'Out' is not defined`. Also, please have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71849860/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71846619/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71612734/17865804) on how to perform and return ML predictions.

Comment: Solved with  `Body(..., embed=True)` Thanks Chris.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `text` attribute, as is currently defined, is expected to be a `query` parameter, **not** `body` (JSON) parameter. Hence, you can either send it as a `query` parameter when `POST`ing your request, or define it using [`Body`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-fields/) field (e.g., `text: str = Body(..., embed=True)`), so that is expected in the body of the request as `JSON`. Please have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774077/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) for more details.