# Process body as plain text in FastAPI and show in SwaggerUI

Tags: python, fastapi

I am trying to have my FastAPI accept a string as body. Note that this string is not a JSON. For me it is important that the body argument can also be specified in the SwaggerUI that FastAPI provides.
At the moment, I am doing the following:

```
@app.put("items/{item_name}")
async def put(item_name: str, body: str = Body(..., media_type="text/plain")):
   print(body)
```

But it gives me an error: Error: Unprocessable Entity

Comment: I tried you method about body, it's valid. My FastAPI is `0.80.0`. You can add more detail about you code.

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70774077/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804).

Answer (score 0):

I hope it fixes:

Create your pydantic model:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
class Item(BaseModel):
     item_name: str
     body: str
```

(if you create it in same page):

```
@app.put("items/{item_name}")
async def put(item_name: Item.item_name, body: Item.body):
   return body
```

Also it is better to use "id"s to update something.

Comment: When I do that I get "AttributeError: type object 'item' has no attribute 'item_name'"

Comment: Be careful about uppercase "Item" > item_name: Item.item_name