# FastAPI shows 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Good evening everyone. I'm trying to make a request to add new user to my database using FastAPI. When I try to do this through the python console app, FastAPI shows me this message:

```
{
     'detail': [
         {
             'loc': ['body', 'nickname'],
             'msg': 'field required',
             'type': 'value_error.missing'
         },
         {
             'loc': ['body', 'password'],
             'msg': 'field required',
             'type': 'value_error.missing'
         },
         {
             'loc': ['body', 'email'],
             'msg': 'field required',
             'type': 'value_error.missing'
         }
    ]
}
```

But when I do this request in `/docs` everything is working!

Here is my pydantic model:

```py
class GetUserModel(BaseModel):
    nickname: str
    password: str
    email: str

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

Here is my handler:

```py
@users_router.post("/users/", status_code=200)
def add_new_user(user: GetUserModel, session: Session = Depends(get_session)):
    user.password = bcrypt.hashpw(
        user.password.encode(),
        bcrypt.gensalt()
    )  # password hashing

    new_user = User(**user.dict())
    add(session, new_user)  # adding to database
```

And here I'm trying to make a request:

```py
response = requests.post(
                    'http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/',
                    data={
                        "nickname": "1",
                        "password": "1",
                        "email": "1"
                    })
print(response.json())
```

If you know what can be the problem, please tell me, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: try `request.post(url,json={your data dict})` i think it typically wants json data not normal form data (you can make it accept form data... but sending json is pretty easy)

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804).

Answer (score 3):

As per the comments on your question, in order for your request to work, you need to perform the `request` with the `json` argument, as with `data` FastAPI assumes that you are sending Form Data:

```
response = requests.post(
    url='http://127.0.0.1:8000/users/',
    json={
        "nickname": "1",
        "password": "1",
        "email": "1"
    }
)
```

But, if you really want to send form data instead, you need to change your endpoint to accept [`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) params:

```
@users_router.post("/users/", status_code=200)
def add_new_user(
    nickname: str = Form(),
    password: str = Form(),
    email: str = Form(),
    session: Session = Depends(get_session)
):
    -- Endpoint handling here ---
```