# FastAPI: 'value_error.missing' when parameter present in query

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic

Here is my FastAPI method

```py
class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str 
    age: int 
    year: str

...

@app.post('/create-student/{student_id}')
def create_student(student_id : int, student : Student):
    db = connect_ddb()
    try:        
        response = db.put_item(Item={
            'id': {'S': f'{student_id}'},
            'student': {'M': student.model_dump()}
        })        
        return {"response message": response}            
    
    except Exception as error: 
        return {"error message": error}
```

Now when I submit a POST using requests...

```py
x = requests.post('endpoint/create-student/4',            
                headers = {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
                            },                  
                 json={
                    "id": 4, 
                    "student": {
                          "name":"Guy",
                          "age": 18,
                          "year": "year 12"
                    }
                 }                  
         
            )
```

Yet `x.json()` returns

```
{'detail': [{'loc': ['body', 'name'],
   'msg': 'field required',
   'type': 'value_error.missing'},
  {'loc': ['body', 'age'],
   'msg': 'field required',
   'type': 'value_error.missing'},
  {'loc': ['body', 'year'],
   'msg': 'field required',
   'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}
```

What does it mean for these elements to be missing from the body?

I'm following this highly rated Q/A advice, so seems like this should be a non-issue... [FastAPI shows 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70815650/fastapi-shows-msg-field-required-type-value-error-missing)

It's present in the json payload. So I'm very confused where (else) it should be and how I might alter the FastAPI method to mitigate this issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are just incorrectly calling the endpoint.

`app.py` file:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Student(BaseModel):
    name: str
    age: int
    year: str


@app.post("/create-student/{student_id}")
def create_student(student_id: int, student: Student):
    print(student_id, student)
```

Calling the endpoint:

```py
import requests

id = 4
response = requests.post(
    url=f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/create-student/{id}",
    headers={"Content-Type": "application/json"},
    data='{"name": "Guy", "age": 18, "year": "year 12"}',
    # can also do the following, equivalent
    # json={"name": "Guy", "age": 18, "year": "year 12"},

)

print(response.json())
```

Your error:
The JSON shows missing `name`, `age`, and `year` only because they are inside the `student`, which should be out instead.

Comment: Unfortunately, this approach doesn’t work, either. The three errors are replaced by one: that student is missing.

Comment: If this is giving you an error, something else is going on. I tested the minimal solution I showed above, and it works successfully. Feel free to replicate the code exactly mentioned and let me know if it still does not work.

Comment: Was the model dump method. Supported in new pydantic but not the version that fast api depend on