# FastApi: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Tags: python, fastapi, pydantic, http-status-code-422

I'm getting this error while trying to accept a pedantic model. After debugging for quite some time I believe the problem is with accepting `CodeCreate`

**Pydantic model**

```
class BaseCode(BaseModel):
    index: Optional[int] = Field(None)
    email: EmailStr
    gen_time: datetime
    expire_time: datetime


class CodeCreate(BaseCode):
    code: int
    used_time: Optional[datetime] = Field(None)

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True

class Message(BaseModel):
    message: str
```

**Code ORM**

```
class Code(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'code'

    index = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    code = Column(Integer)
    email = Column(String, ForeignKey('user.email'))
    gen_time = Column(DateTime)
    expire_time = Column(DateTime)
    used_time = Column(DateTime, nullable=True)
```

**Handler**

```
@app.post('/verify-code', response_model=schemas.Message, responses={404: {"model": schemas.Message}, 406: {"model": schemas.Message}})
async def verify_code(code: schemas.CodeCreate, response: Response, device_name: str = Body(..., embed=True), db=Depends(get_db)):

    result = crud.verify_and_insert_code(db=db, code=code)
    if result == 'matched':
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED
        return crud.start_new_session(db=db, session=schemas.Session(session_id='1234', start_time=datetime.now(), email=code.email, device_name=device_name))
    elif result == 'not-matched':
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_200_OK
    elif result == 'expire':
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_406_NOT_ACCEPTABLE
    elif result == 'invalid':
        response.status_code = status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND

    return schemas.Message(message="Item not found")
```

**Body of request from the client**

```
{
  "code": {
    "index": 0,
    "email": "user@example.com",
    "gen_time": "2022-01-24T16:38:12.612Z",
    "expire_time": "2022-01-24T16:38:12.612Z",
    "code": 0,
    "used_time": "2022-01-24T16:38:12.612Z"
  },
  "device_name": "string"
}
```

**Response body for 422**

```
{
  "detail": [
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "code",
        "email"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "code",
        "gen_time"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "code",
        "expire_time"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    },
    {
      "loc": [
        "body",
        "code",
        "code"
      ],
      "msg": "field required",
      "type": "value_error.missing"
    }
  ]
}
```

**Temporary Solution**

Removing this ORM confirmation code from Pydantic model solves the issue. I believe there might be a clash between `CodeCreate` pydantic model and `Code` ORM model, but I don't know how to resolve it.

```
class Config:
    orm_mode = True
```

Comment: The body of FastAPIs 422 response contains an error message telling you exactly which part of your request doesn't match the expected format.

Comment: Future readers may find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution after debugging for quite a while.

The `ORM` configured pedantic model can't be used to receive requests from the client.

In my case, I had to create another class that extends the `CodeCreate` class add `ORM` configuration to that class and use `CodeCreate` for body from the client.

```
class BaseCode(BaseModel):
    index: Optional[int] = Field(None)
    email: EmailStr
    gen_time: datetime
    expire_time: datetime


class CodeCreate(BaseCode):
    code: int
    used_time: Optional[datetime] = Field(None)

    
class Code(CodeCreate):

    class Config:
            orm_mode = True
```

**Post request**

```
@app.post('/verify-code')
async def verify_code(code: schemas.CodeCreate):
    return 'success'
```

Answer (score 5):

The `422 Unprocessable Entity` error because of **ContentType** is incorrect. The FastAPI/Pydantic need `ContentType = application/json` to parse request body.

Are you sure **your POST request has ContentType header is** **application/json**?

If not add it!

Answer (score 0):

According to MDN
[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/422),
a `422 Unprocessable Entity` means that the information of the request could not be processed.

In this case, the most likely problem is that the data of the `POST` request that is sent does not match with the Pydantic model.

Make sure the data that is sent is in the correct format.

Answer (score 0):

Just as stated above by Brian Law, your request body is in the form of `Code`, which is not a pydantic model, but a database one.

When you send the `POST` request, the body should match up with `CodeCreate`, not `Code`.

Comment: How is it not according to the `CodeCreate`?

Comment: This request body is suggested by Swagger UI?

Comment: Are you sure you can inherit pydantic models from each other?

Comment: Yes, it's documented. Here
https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/#create-the-pydantic-models