# FastAPI server returns "422 unprocessable entity" - value_error.missing

Tags: python, api, backend, crud, fastapi

```
from http.client import responses
from random import randrange
from tkinter.tix import STATUS
from typing import Optional
from urllib import response
from fastapi import Body, FastAPI, Response ,status, HTTPException
from pydantic import BaseModel

app= FastAPI()

class Post(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    Published: bool = True
    rating: Optional[int] = None

my_post = [{"title": "title of post 1", "content": "content of post 1", "id": 2},{"title": "title of post 2","content":"content of post 2", "id":3}]

def find_post(id):
    for p in my_post:
        if p["id"] == id:
         return p

def find_index_post(id):
    for i,p in enumerate(my_post):
        if p["id"]== id:

            return i 



@app.get("/posts/{id}")
def get_posts(id: int , response: Response):
    post= find_post(id)
    if not post :

        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail= f"post with id {id} not found bludd")


        # response.status_code=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        # return {"message": f" post with id : {id} not found"}

    return{"here is the post": post}  

@app.delete("/posts/{id}", status_code= status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)
def delete_post(id: int):
    index= find_index_post(id)
    if index == None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code= status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail= f"post with id {id} does not exist")
    my_post.pop(index)
    
    return Response(status_code= status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

@app.put("/posts/{id}")
def update_post(id: int , post: Post):
    index = find_index_post(id)
    if index == None :
        raise HTTPException(status_code= status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, detail= f"post with id {id} does not exist")
    post_dict = my_post.dict()
    post_dict["id"]= id
    my_post[index]= post_dict
    return {"message" : "updated post"}
```

Everything else works, but the `put/update` function at the end.
Literally coding along with a tutorial and have non-stop irritating issues.

Python console says:  `422 Unprocessable Entity`.

Postman says:

```
"detail": 
"loc":
"body","msg": "field required",
"type": "value_error.missing"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `422 unprocessable entity` error tells exactly which part of your request doesn't match the expected format or is missing. In your case, it says that the `body` is missing. When using Pydantic models, you essentially declare a `JSON` object (or Python dict), and hence, your endpoint expects a [request body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/) in JSON format. Thus, the request you send must include a `JSON` payload matching the Pydantic model. Below is an example using Python requests (more details can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975923/17865804)), but you could also use OpenAPI/Swagger UI autodocs at http://127.0.0.1:8000/docs to test the API. Also, please have a look at [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) for more details and examples on `422 unprocessable entity` error when posting JSON data.

### Example

**app.py**

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Post(BaseModel):
    title: str
    content: str
    published: bool = True
    rating: Optional[int] = None

# ...

@app.put('/posts/{id}')
def update_post(id: int , post: Post):
    pass
```

**test.py**

```py
import requests

post_id = 2
url = f'http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/{post_id}'
payload = {"title": "string", "content": "string", "published": True, "rating": 0}
resp = requests.put(url, json=payload)
print(resp.json())
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that makes sense as it's an update function. Thanks so much!

Comment: I'm just self-teaching and programming just gets deeper and deeper. Real workout for the mind and understanding these systems.