# Webhook listener in FastAPI raises 422 Unprocessable Entity error

Tags: python, json, fastapi, webhooks, http-status-code-422

I have a webhook listener that uses an `APIRouter` to designate the route for the application on the FastAPI server. The app should receive a `POST` request (expecting data in JSON format) and log this to the console. However, I am getting consistent redirects. I have attempted the following with curl:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
'http://127.0.0.1:8010/webhook' \
-H 'accept: application/json' \
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
-d '{"data": {"UK":"test"}}'
```

The listener:

```py
import hmac
from logging import Logger, info
from fastapi import APIRouter, FastAPI, Header, Request, Response
from router.router1 import rout
from pydantic import BaseModel

WEBHOOK_SECRET = '123-456-789'

class WebhookResponse(BaseModel):
    result: str

class WebhookData(BaseModel):
    body: dict

app = FastAPI()
rout = APIRouter()

@app.get("/")
async def welcome() -> dict:
    return { "message": 'Hello World!' }

def printLog(data):
    info(f"Raw data: {data}")

@rout.post("/webhook", response_model=WebhookResponse, status_code=200)
async def webhook(
    webhook_input: WebhookData,
    request: Request,
    response: Response,
    content_length: int = Header(...),
    x_hook_signature: str = Header(None)
):
    if content_length > 1_000_000:
        # To prevent memory allocation attacks
        Logger.error(f"Content too long ({content_length})")
        response.status_code = 400
        return {"result": "Content too long"}
    if x_hook_signature:
        raw_input = await request.body()
        input_hmac = hmac.new(
            key=WEBHOOK_SECRET.encode(),
            msg=raw_input,
            digestmod="sha512"
        )
        if not hmac.compare_digest(
                input_hmac.hexdigest(),
                x_hook_signature
        ):
            Logger.error("Invalid message signature")
            response.status_code = 400
            return {"result": "Invalid message signature"}
        Logger.info("Message signature checked ok")
    else:
        Logger.info("No message signature to check")
    printLog(webhook_input)
    return {"result": "ok"}

app.include_router(rout)
```

Curl prints out the following error:

```json
{
    "detail": [
        {
            "loc": [
                "body"
            ],
            "msg": "value is not a valid dict",
            "type": "type_error.dict"
        }
    ]
}
```

With the following printed to console:

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:50192 - "POST /webhook/ HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

Comment: If you add the `-L` option to your curl request, curl will follow the redirect.

Comment: This is a separate question to your one before. You should rather create a separate SO question and revert this one.

Comment: The body of the 422 error will have information about exactly what was missing; but please don't edit questions to change the meaning of them as the comments and the (now deleted) answer otherwise is out of place.

Answer (score 0):

You called your dict “data” in your curl , should be called “body”.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `data` as the field name for the body content that you are sending in the curl request, whereas in the Pydantic model this is defined as `body`. Hence, the error that is being raised complaining about the body `value is not a valid dict`. The curl requet's body should instead look like this (using the same field name given in your backend):

```json
{
  "body": {"UK":"test"}
}
```

I would suggest you have a look at similar posts about **how to post JSON data** [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804), [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804), as well as [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73906755/17865804) and [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971004/17865804). Also, you can use the [auto-generated docs](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/features/#automatic-docs) provided by OpenAPI specification and Swagger UI at `/docs`, which would allow you to see the expected format of the data, as well as provide you with the relevant Curl command.