# FastAPI - "msg": "value is not a valid dict" in schema request

Tags: python, json, fastapi, pydantic

My code:

```py
@app.post('/create')
async def createUser(request: UserRequest, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
      print(request)
      _user = crud.createUser(db, user_schema=request.parameter)    
      return _user
```

Schema:

```py
class UserSchema(BaseModel):

# id: Optional[int] = None
      username: Optional[str] = None
      password: Optional[str] = None
      email: Optional[str] = None

      class Config:
            orm_mode = True
    
    
class UserRequest(BaseModel):
       parameter: UserSchema = Field(...)
```

The error:

```json
"loc": "body"
"msg": "value is not a valid dict",
"type": "type_error.dict"
```

Comment: Related answers can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74237131/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71874694/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71471293/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71439821/17865804).

Comment: What was the HTTP request look like?