# wordpress: wp_remote_post can't pass body to the fast api, while from api docs and python requests no issue, error msg: value is not a valid dict, 422

Tags: python, php, json, wordpress

background: I am trying to make a fastapi and wordpress plugin which will use api in localhost (both sits on the same server), i have developed the api and its working perfectly fine through swagger ui and python request library however can't use it in the plugin through wp_remote_post

code for the api:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel
from api.article import add_article, html_format_data

app = FastAPI()

class PostData(BaseModel):
    links: list
    title: str

@app.post('/create_post/')
def create_post(post_data: PostData):
    html_format = html_format_data(post_data.links, post_data.title)  # list of dicts
    if add_article(post_data.title, html_format):
        return {"status": 201, "success": True}
    else:
        return {"error"}
```

python request code:

```py
import requests

data = {
    "title": "gaming",
    "links": [
        {
            "id": "video id 1",
            "thumbnail": "url of thumbnail 1,
            "title": "title of video 1"
        },
        {
            "id": "video id 2",
            "thumbnail": "url of thumbnail 2 ,
            "title": "title of video 2"
        }
    ]
  }
res = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_post/', json=data)
print(res.content)
```

same success through swagger ui:

```js
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_post/' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{
  "links": [
  {
    "id": "shortand",
    "thumbnail": "shortand",
    "title": "shortand"
  },
  {
    "id": "shortand",
    "thumbnail": "shortand",
    "title": "shortand"
  }
],
  "title": "gaming"
}'
```

but when i do it through wordpress plugin which code is below:

```php
function create_post( $data, $query ) {
    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_post/';
    
    $arguments = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body' => json_encode(array(
                "links" => $data,
                "title" => $query
                )),
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'accept' => 'application/json'
            )
        );
    
    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $arguments );
//  echo '<script>console.log(`data: ' . $arguments["body"] . '`)</script>';
    echo '<script>console.log(`' . json_encode($response) . '`)</script>';
}
```

i get this error in the console:

`{"headers":{},"body":"{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"value is not a valid dict","type":"type_error.dict"}]}","response":{"code":422,"message":"Unprocessable Entity"},"cookies":[],"filename":null,"http_response":{"data":null,"headers":null,"status":null}}`

i am new to wordpress and php.
i did consult these solutions but nothing seem to work as i am doing in from php.

[POST request response 422 error {'detail': [{'loc': ['body'], 'msg': 'value is not a valid dict', 'type': 'type_error.dict'}]}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71470236/post-request-response-422-error-detail-loc-body-msg-value-is-n)

[FastAPI - "msg": "value is not a valid dict" in schema request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74426590/fastapi-msg-value-is-not-a-valid-dict-in-schema-request)

**EDIT**
i did the below as suggested BUT still getting the same error, heres the php code:

```php
function create_post( $data, $query ) {
    $url = 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/create_post/';
    $data_arr = array("links" => $data,"title" => $query);
    $data_obj = (object) $data_arr;
    
    $body = json_encode( $data_obj );

    $arguments = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body' => $body,
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'accept' => 'application/json'
            )
        );
    
    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $arguments );
    echo '<script>console.log(`' . $body . '`)</script>';
    echo '<script>console.log(`' . json_encode($response) . '`)</script>';
}
```

**SOLVED**
lol my issue was a idiotic, i missed the "s" in headers so it want any json anymore because it cant see headers so it couldnt find it json thats why it was giving the error not a valid dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When handling JSON from php, we sometimes run into problems with the distinction between objects and associative arrays.

Try casting your body array as an object before giving it to `json_encode()`, something like this:

```php
    $body = json_encode( (object)
               array(
                "links" => $data,
                "title" => $query
               ));
    print_r ($body);  //debugging: examine JSON to pass to web service
    $arguments = array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'body'   => $body,
        'header' => array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            'accept' => 'application/json'
            )
        );
    
    $response = wp_remote_post( $url, $arguments );
```