# How to pass a pydantic model to an endpoint defined in FastAPI with Python

Tags: python, rest, fastapi, pydantic

I am currently learning the FastAPI framework and pydantic models and I got a question regarding how to pass these pydantic models to the API when calling the endpoint.

I am mostly following this tutorial: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/sql-databases/

This is a part of my code where I define the pydantic models:

```
class ChatMessageBase(BaseModel):
    sender_id: int
    receiver_id: int
    message_content: str
    

class ChatMessageCreate(ChatMessageBase):
    pass
 
class ChatMessage(ChatMessageBase):
    message_id: int
    #TODO datetime validator einbauen
    time_created: str
    
    class Config:
        orm_mode = True
```

And this is the endpoint defined in FastAPI. The crud.create_chat_message is just the communication method for the database, this is working properly.

```
@app.post("/assistant_chat/")
def create_chat_message(chat_message: schema.ChatMessageCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    return crud.create_chat_message(db=db, chat_message=chat_message)
```

Now I am trying to test this endpoint with the requests module, the problem is that I do not understand how the json body should like in order to work. FastAPI says that it automatically maps the json body to the pydantic model but how does the framework know which int for example is the sender_id and which int is the receiver_id.

Maybe someone can help me with an explaination.
Thank you

Comment: In addition to the link above, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70971004/17865804), [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70975923/17865804), as well as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75359262/17865804)

Answer (score 0):

You need to send it as key value pairs

```
{
    "sender_id": 0,
    "receiver_id": 0,
    "message_content": "string"
}
```