# 422 Unprocessable Entity error in FastAPI when I try to upload an image using React frontend

Tags: python, reactjs, fastapi, http-status-code-422

this code works perfectly when i hit this api using swagger ui. but fails to perform when its being hit from a react frontend showing status code `422 unprocessable entity`. below is my fastapi endpoint-

```
@post.post('/post')
async def create_post(post_text: str, image: bytes = File(None), token: str = Depends(oauth2_scheme), db: Session = Depends(database.get_db)):
    user_info = await services.get_user_info(token)
    username = user_info["username"]
    print(username)
    image_url = None
    if image:
        # Generate a unique filename for the image
        image_filename = f"{username}_{uuid.uuid4().hex}.jpg"
        # print(image_filename)

        # Save the image to bytes and send to MinIO bucket
        # image_bytes = await image.read()
        image_bytes = base64.b64decode(image.split(",")[1])

        minio_client.put_object(
            "minilinkedindistributed",
            image_filename,
            io.BytesIO(image_bytes),  
            length=len(image_bytes),
            content_type="image/jpeg"
        )

        # Construct the image URL based on MinIO server URL and bucket name
        image_url = f"http://127.0.0.1:9000/minilinkedindistributed/{image_filename}"
        print(image_url)
    elif image is None or image.filename == '':
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Invalid or empty image file')
    # Create the post
    new_post = services.make_post(db, username, post_text, image_url)

    headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}

    # Get all users (except the one who posted)
    async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
        response = await client.get("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/all_users_except_poster", headers=headers)

    if response.status_code == 200:
        all_users_except_poster = response.json()
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail="Failed to fetch users from user service")

    # Create a notification for each user
    for user_to_notify in all_users_except_poster:
        notification_data = {
            'notification_text': f"{username} made a new post...",
            'pid' : new_post.id,
            'username' : user_to_notify["username"],
            'notification_datetime' : datetime.utcnow().isoformat(),
            'is_read' : False
        }

        
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            response = await client.post("http://127.0.0.1:8002/api/v1/notification", json=notification_data, headers=headers)

        if response.status_code != 200:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=response.status_code, detail="Failed to send notification")
    

    return{"message" : new_post}
```

and below is my react component-

```
const HomePage = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([]);
  const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
  const [postText, setPostText] = useState('');
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const [notifications, setNotifications] = useState([]);
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    const access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    if (access_token) {
      setLoggedIn(true);
      fetchPosts(access_token);
    }
  }, []);


  const handlePostTextChange = (event) => {
    setPostText(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleImageChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedImage(event.target.files[0]);
  };

  const handleSubmitPost = async () => {
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('post_text', postText); // Make sure 'postText' holds the user's post text
    if (selectedImage) {
      formData.append('image', selectedImage, selectedImage.name); // Make sure 'selectedImage' holds the user's selected image
    }else console.log('Invalid or empty image file');
    console.log("Post Text:", postText);
    console.log("Selected Image:", selectedImage);
    console.log('FormData:', formData);

    const access_token = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
  
    // Make a POST request to create a new post
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(`${API_BASE_URL}/post`, formData, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`,
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', // Set the correct content type for the form data
        },
      });

      // Refresh the posts after successful submission
      fetchPosts(access_token);
      
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error submitting post:', error.response);
    }

  };
```

stuck here since ages,
any solution will help.
thank you

i tried googling and also saw some stackoverflow solutions but i tried all of them still it didnt work. even chatgpt failed to solve it. Need the solution as fast as possible

Comment: The body of the 422 error will include information about exactly what value is missing. It's a good place to start looking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the [422 (unprocessable entity) response includes an error message](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) about exactly which part/value in your request is missing or doesn't match the expected format. Hence, please make sure to have a look at that and include it in your question.

In your case, you seem to be using `axios` in the frontend to post `Form` data to the FastAPI backend. However, the way the `post_text` argument is defined in your endpoint is expected as **query**, not `Form`, parameter.

**`post_text` expected as query parameter**

```py
@app.post('/create')
async def create_post(post_text: str):
    pass
```

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74536449/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72068032/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73761724/17865804) (please refer to those posts for more details and examples):

> When you declare other function parameters that are not part of the
> path parameters, they are **automatically** interpreted as "query"
> parameters.

Hence, if you would like `post_text` to be a `Form` parameter, it should instead be declared as follows:

**`post_text` expected as `Form` parameter**

```py
from fastapi import Form

@app.post('/create')
async def create_post(post_text: str = Form(...)):
    pass
```

Related answers demonstrating how to post `File`/`Form` data to FastAPI backend through `axios` or `fetch` request in the frontend can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74507628/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71023536/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72029319/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804).

Comment: using post_text as Form parameter did the job alhamdulillah. thank you for your help!