# How to pass **kwargs as params to FastAPI endpoint?

Tags: python, json, fastapi, optional-parameters, keyword-argument

I have a function generating a `dict` template. This function consists of several generators and requires one parameter (i.e., `carrier`) and has many optional parameters (keyword arguments - `**kwargs`).

```py
def main_builder(carrier, **params):
    output = SamplerBuilder(DEFAULT_JSON)
    output.generate_flight(carrier)
    output.generate_airline_info(carrier)
    output.generate_locations()
    output.generate_passengers()
    output.generate_contact_info()
    output.generate_payment_card_info()
    output.configs(**params)
    result = output.input_json
    return result 

# example of function call
examplex = main_builder("3M", proxy="5.39.69.171:8888", card=Visa, passengers={"ADT":2, "CHD":1}, bags=2)
```

I want to deploy this function to FastAPI endpoint. I managed to do it for `carrier` but how can I set `**kwargs` as params to the function?

```
@app.get("/carrier/{carrier_code}", response_class=PrettyJSONResponse) # params/kwargs??
async def get_carrier(carrier_code):
    output_json = main_builder(carrier_code)
    return airline_input_json
```

Comment: `json` payload preferably but would like to see both solutions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using Pydantic Model

Since your function *"..has many optional parameters"* and `passengers` parameter requires a dictionary as an input, I would suggest creating a Pydantic model, where you define the parameters, and which would allow you sending the data in `JSON` format and getting them automatically validated by Pydantci as well. Once the endpoint is called, you can use Pydantic's [`dict()`](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/usage/exporting_models/#modeldict) method (**Note:** In Pydantic V2, `dict()` was replaced by `model_dump()`—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76761451/17865804) for more details) to convert the model into a dictionary.

##### Example

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel
from typing import Optional

class MyModel(BaseModel):
    proxy: Optional[str] = None
    card: Optional[str] = None
    passengers: Optional[dict] = None 
    bags: Optional[int] = None

@app.post("/carrier/{carrier_code}")
async def get_carrier(carrier_code: int, m: MyModel):
    return main_builder(carrier_code, **m.dict())  # In Pydantic V2, use **m.model_dump()
```

### Sending arbitrary JSON data

In case you had to send **arbitrary** JSON data, and hence, pre-defining the parameters of an endpoint wouldn't be possible, you could use an approach similar to the one described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) (see Options 3 and 4), as well as [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74173023/17865804).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. When I run the API (`docker-compose up`) it works but when I try to get to `http://0.0.0.0:8080/carrier/3M` (3M is carrier code) without any parameters I get reponse code 422: `422 Unprocessable Entity` and in browser I get an error `{"detail":[{"loc":["body"],"msg":"field required","type":"value_error.missing"}]}` Am I missing something?

Comment: @PetrSevcik I think you need to use default values, `carrier_code: int = None` ...worked for me.