# How to fix Pydantic's deprecation warning about using model.dict() method?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, fastapi, pydantic, deprecation-warning

When I use `.dict()` method on a Pydantic model in FastAPI, it gives me a deprecation warning. I upgraded `pydantic` through command line, but it still shows the same error. I also updated VScode, but same problem.

Comment: Why would you expect version upgrades to get rid of deprecation warnings? If anything version upgrades will result in those warning becoming actual errors since it might have actually been removed after being a warning for a few versions... The solution is here to use whatever alternative the framework offers and not rely on a deprecated feature.

Comment: Show full error messages and your sample code.

Comment: In pydatic 2.+ `dict` is replaced by `model_dump` (see [migration guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/))

Answer (score 12):

In Pydantic V2 `.dict()` has been changed to [`.model_dump()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/#modelmodel_dump) (similarly, `.json()` has been replaced by [`.model_dump_json()`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/#modelmodel_dump_json)). You can find more details at the [Migration guide](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/migration/#migration-guide), [Model methods and properties](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/models/#model-methods-and-properties), as well as the relevant documention of the methods provided above.

Note that Pydantic models can also be converted to dictionaries using [`dict(model)`](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/usage/serialization/#dictmodel-and-iteration). With this approach the raw field values are returned, so sub-models will not be converted to dictionaries. Either `.model_dump()` or `dict(model)` will provide a `dict` of fields, but `.model_dump()` can take numerous other arguments—such as `mode`, for instance, which is useful when dealing with non-JSON serializable objects (see the [relevant documentation](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/api/base_model/#pydantic.main.BaseModel.model_dump))—as well as will recursively convert nested models into dicts.