# Use FastAPI to parse incoming POST request from Slack

Tags: python, slack, fastapi, slack-api, slack-commands

I'm building a FastAPI server to receive requests sent by slack slash command. Using the code below, I could see that the following:

```
token=BLAHBLAH&team_id=BLAHBLAH&team_domain=myteam&channel_id=BLAHBLAH&channel_name=testme&user_id=BLAH&user_name=myname&command=%2Fwhatever&text=test&api_app_id=BLAHBLAH&is_enterprise_install=false&response_url=https%3A%2F%2Fhooks.slack.com%2Fcommands%BLAHBLAH&trigger_id=BLAHBLAHBLAH
```

was printed, which is exactly the payload I saw in the [official docs](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#app_command_handling). I'm trying to use the payload information to do something, and I'm curious whether there's a great way of parsing this payload info. I can definitely parse this payload using split function or any other beautiful functions, but I'm curious whether there is a 'de facto' way of dealing with slack payload. Thanks in advance!

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Request

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
async def root(request: Request):
    request_body = await request.body()
    print(request_body)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Receive `JSON` data

You would normally use [Pydantic models to declare a request body](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body/)—if you were about to receive data in `JSON` form—thus benefiting from the automatic validation that [Pydantic](https://pydantic-docs.helpmanual.io/) has to offer (for more options on how to post `JSON` data, have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804)). So, you would have to define a model like this:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Item(BaseModel):
    token: str
    team_id: str
    team_domain: str
    # etc.

@app.post("/")
def root(item: Item):
    print(item.dict())  # convert to dictionary (if required)
    return item
```

The payload would look like this:

```py
{
    "token": "gIkuvaNzQIHg97ATvDxqgjtO"
    "team_id": "Foo",
    "team_domain": "bar",
    # etc.
}
```

### Receive `Form` data

If, however, you were about to receive the payload as [`Form` data](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/), just like what slack API does (as shown in the [link](https://api.slack.com/interactivity/slash-commands#app_command_handling) you provided), you could use [`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) fileds. With `Form` fields, your payload will still be validated against those fields and the type you define them with. You would need, however, to define all the parameters in the endpoint, as described in the above link and as shown below:

```py
from fastapi import  Form

@app.post("/")
def root(token: str = Form(...), team_id: str = Form(...), team_domain: str = Form(...)):
    return {"token": token, "team_id": team_id, "team_domain": team_domain}
```

or to avoid specifying the parameters in an endpoint, in case you had a great number of `Form` fields, you could create a [custom dependency class](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/#classes-as-dependencies_1) (using the [`@dataclass`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) decorator, for simplicity), which would allow you to define multiple `Form` fields inside a separate class, and only use that class definition in your endpoint—see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74011067/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74019824/17865804) for more details on FastAPI dependencies. Example:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass
from fastapi import FastAPI, Form, Depends

@dataclass
class Item:
    token: str = Form(...)
    team_id: str = Form(...)
    team_domain: str = Form(...)
    #...

@app.post("/")
def root(data: Item = Depends()):
    return data
```

As FastAPI is actually Starlette underneath, even if you still had to access the request body in the way you do in the question, you should rather use methods such as `request.json()` or `request.form()`, as described in [Starlette documentation](https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body), which would allow you to get the request body parsed as `JSON` or `form-data`, respectively. Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76971147/17865804) for more details and examples.