# FastAPI: React native frontend giving 422 error during auth flow

Tags: javascript, python, react-native, axios, fastapi

My react native code:

```
const signin =
  (dispatch) =>
  async ({ username, password }) => {
    try {
      console.log(username, password);
      const response = await tracker.post(
        "/login",
        (data = { username, password }),
        (headers = {
          "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        })
      );
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
      dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: response.data.token });
      console.log(response.data.token);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch({
        type: "error",
        payload: "This is an error, start debugging",
      });
    }
  };
```

Curl request to FastAPI backend:

```
curl -X 'POST' \  'https://fastest.herokuapp.com/login/' \   -H 'accept: application/json' \   -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \   -d 'grant_type=&username={email}&password={password}&scope=&client_id=&client_secret=
```

whenever I try to create a new user or sign in with an existing user I keep getting following error:

```
[AxiosError: Request failed with status code 422]
```

Is there a better way to send a POST request with curl to signup or login using axios?

Now, I know this is a well documented error on internet, but, somehow, I am unable to find the error and debug it. Any feedback as to what I am doing wrong?

Edit:
FastAPI endpoint code:

```
@router.post("/",response_model=schemas.Token)
def getLogin(user_Credentials:OAuth2PasswordRequestForm=Depends(),db: Session=Depends(database.get_db)):
    user = db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.email == user_Credentials.username).first()
    if not user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail=f"wrong credentials")

    if not utils.verify(user_Credentials.password,user.password):
        raise HTTPException(status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN, detail=f"wrong credentials")

    access_token = oauth2.create_access_token(data={"user_id": user.id})
    return {"access_token":access_token, "token_type":"bearer"}
```

###### For full code:

Backend FastAPI: [here](https://github.com/bhavyasharma95/FastAPI-quickstart)
Frontend react native: [here](https://github.com/bhavyasharma95/Reactnative-Quickstart)

****************Error Changed****************

After adding `qs.stringify()` according to https://axios-http.com/docs/urlencoded and updating the code as follows:

```
const signin =
  (dispatch) =>
  async ({ username, password }) => {
    try {
      console.log(username, password);
      const response = await tracker({
        method: "post",
        url: "/login",
        data: qs.stringify({
          username: username,
          password: password,
        }),
        headers: {
          "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=utf-8",
        },
      });
      console.log(response.data.token);
      await AsyncStorage.setItem("token", response.data.token);
      dispatch({ type: "signin", payload: response.data.token });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      dispatch({
        type: "error",
        payload: "Start debuggin",
      });
    }
  };
```

the problem arises now is that token is `undefined`, but the when I enter same credentials on `/docs` I get the token.

Final update: got the endpoint wrong for token access

Answer (score 1):

Please try to send your authentication data as FormData.

```
let bodyFormData = new FormData();
bodyFormData.append("username", "value");
bodyFormData.append("password", "value");
```

then send it as you did:

```
 const response = await tracker.post(
        "/login",
        (data = bodyFormData),
        (headers = {
          "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        })
      );
```

It should be mentioned that I didn't do much with react-native, but I guess this work for your case.

Comment: I did try that but it only changed the error message from 422 to network error.

Answer (score 1):

As per [JavaScript's documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined#description):

> A variable that has not been assigned a value is of type `undefined`.
> A method or statement also returns `undefined` if the variable that is
> being evaluated does not have an assigned value. A function returns
> `undefined` if a value was not returned.

In your case, you attempt to retrieve an attribute, namely `token`, from the JSON repsonse returned by your FastAPI backend. However, such an attribute does not exist in that JSON object. Your API endpoint returns `"access_token": access_token`, hence, you should instead use `response.data.access_token`.

Also, for future reference, a response having status code `422` (`unprocessable entity`) will have a response body that specifies the error message, telling exactly which part of your request is missing or doesn’t match the expected format. This will guide you to fix the error in your code. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) as well.