# 422 Unprocessable Entity error when uploading File using JavaScript Fetch API to FastAPI backend

Tags: javascript, python, fetch, fastapi, form-data

The codes are as shown below.

**Backend**

```py
api.py

@app.post("/caption")
async def caption(image: UploadFile = File(...)) -> str:
    # produce the caption
    caption = apiCaption(image)

    # save the image and caption information
    status = await apiSaveData(image, caption)

    return caption if status else "Something went wrong"
```

**Frontend**

```
submit.js
export default function SubmitButton({ image }) {
  const handleSubmission = async () => {
    let formData = new FormData();
    console.log(image);
    formData.append("file", image);

    await fetch("http://localhost:8000/caption", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData,
    })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log("Caption:", result);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error("Error:", error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button disabled={!image} onClick={handleSubmission}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The server keeps showing:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 422 (Unprocessable Entity) error
```

I really don't know why and the error code is quite ambiguous so cannot get the point.

Comment: Hi , have you added the header to your api call? I mean                  headers: {
    "Content-type": "application/json"
  },   Because I saw a problem similar for 422 status maybe could help -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59929028/python-fastapi-error-422-with-post-request-when-sending-json-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that on client side you use the **same** *key* (parameter's name) given on server side for `UploadFile`. In your case, that is `image`, as shown in this line of your code:

```py
async def caption(image: UploadFile = File(...))
                  ^^^^^
```

Hence, on client side, when appending the file to the `FormData` instance, you should use that key instead:

```js
formData.append("image", image);
```

Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request/70640522#70640522) for more details and examples. Also, for future reference, the 422 status code is not *quite ambiguous*, as you stated. The 422 response body will contain an error message about which field(s) is missing or doesn’t match the expected format, which will help you to resolve the issue.