# How to get Files and Form data using the Request object in FastAPI?

Tags: python, file, fastapi, webhooks, starlette

I am developing a webhook in which a third-party service will hit my URL and will provide some files, now I can not use FastAPI's `UploadFile = File (...)` because it throws an error of the required field **File**
I want to read the payload and files from the request object as we can do in Flask by simply doing this

```
from flask import request
files = request.files
```

How can I achieve the same in FastAPI?

Comment: What is the error you're facing and why exactly can't you use `UploadFile`?

Comment: because I will have to assign a variable inside the function like file; UploadFIle = File(..) and the third party hitting my endpoint is not sending the data like this. they are sending the files in request. 
so I want to read the  files from the request object

Comment: That's what `UploadFile` does; can you show the code and the request that doesn't work as you expect it to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Starlette's [`request.form()`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/212fa46b23be0701a5963cdeff14f05ed352e22a/starlette/requests.py#L245) method to parse the body, which would return a [`FormData`](https://github.com/encode/starlette/blob/212fa46b23be0701a5963cdeff14f05ed352e22a/starlette/datastructures.py#L480) object containing both file uploads and text input. For more details and references, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74015930/17865804), on which the following example is based. Another solution would be to use the approach demonstrated in Option 1 of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73443824/17865804).

Also, if, for any reason, you would like to use a `def` instead of `async def` endpoint, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) on how to read the file contents inside a `def` endpoint. You might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70659178/17865804) helpful as well.

### Working Example

**app.py**

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI, Depends, Request, HTTPException
from starlette.datastructures import FormData

app = FastAPI()

async def get_body(request: Request):
    content_type = request.headers.get('Content-Type')
    if content_type is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='No Content-Type provided!')
    elif (content_type == 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' or
          content_type.startswith('multipart/form-data')):
        try:
            return await request.form()
        except Exception:
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Invalid Form data')
    else:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail='Content-Type not supported!')


@app.post('/')
async def main(body = Depends(get_body)):
    if isinstance(body, FormData):  # if Form/File data received
        msg = body.get('msg')
        items = body.getlist('items')
        files = body.getlist('files')  # returns a list of UploadFile objects
        if files:
            for file in files:
                print(f'Filename: {file.filename}. Content (first 15 bytes): {await file.read(15)}')
        return 'OK'
```

**test.py**

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
data = {'items': ['foo', 'bar'], 'msg': 'Hello!'}
files = [('files', open('a.txt', 'rb')), ('files', open('b.txt', 'rb'))]
 
# Send Form data and files
r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)  
print(r.text)

# Send Form data only
r = requests.post(url, data=data)              
print(r.text)
```

Comment: the code is working but I am getting an empty list of files.

Comment: Please make sure that you are using the **same** name for the `files` parameter as the one used by the third-party service that is calling the API endpoint. In the example above, that name is `files`. Have a look at related posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71176578/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73739720/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70797993/17865804). If that is unknown to you, you could use/print `await request.body()` to get the raw `multipart/form-data` body and extract the name from the `Content-Disposition` header of the file part.