# FastAPI not receiving simple array of strings from Axios

Tags: reactjs, axios, fastapi

I'm stuck.  I think I have tried everything, but nothing seems to work.
I have a simple array in React that looks like this:

["2023-06","2023-07","2023-08","2023-09","2023-10","2023-11","2023-12","2024-01","2024-02","2024-03","2024-04","2024-05"]

which is created by this:

```
  let mydate = JSON.stringify(rowData.map(x => x.Date))
```

I'm trying to post this data to my API service using this:

```
const savePlan = async () => {
  try {
    console.log(mydate)
    const response = await axios.post('/saveplan', {mydate},
    { headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'}}
    );
    console.log("data saved successfully!", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving data', error);
    }
  };
```

this my endpoint

```
@app.post("/saveplan", tags=['save'], status_code=200)
async def savePlan(items: Item):
    dates = items.dates
    return {"received": dates}
```

And the Pydantic model:

```
class Item(BaseModel):
    dates: List[str]
```

and this is the server response:

INFO:     127.0.0.1:59848 - "POST /saveplan HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

does anyone know why this I'm getting a 422 from such a simply array of strings?

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know `FastAPI`, but my guess that the problem is on the client side.

I'll assume the `Date` field is actually a `string` and not a `Date` object, then:

```
let mydate = {
    dates: rowData.map(x => x.Date)
};
```

Otherwise, my suggestion is to serialize as [ISO](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toISOString). However, that probably is somewhat related to `FastAPI`, and I could be wrong.

```
let mydate = {
    dates: rowData.map(x => x.Date.toISOString())
};
```

At this point:

```
const savePlan = async () => {
  try {
    console.log(mydate)
    const response = await axios.post('/saveplan', mydate);
    console.log("data saved successfully!", response.data);
    } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error saving data', error);
    }
  };
```

You don't even need to specify the content-type in the header, because that's implicit.

Comment: correct.  it is a simple string, not even time format.  In the console, it looks like the console image I added above.  I'll give your suggestion a try.  thank you

Comment: gives the same 422...