# Max retries exceeded with url: /predict. Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] on fastapi app

Tags: python, deployment, fastapi

I want to deploy in local a super simple, basic app that uses a ML model I fitted earlier to predict data in my test dataset. This is the format of the fastAPI module:

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import pickle
import numpy as np
# import pandas as pd
import json
from typing import *

app = FastAPI()
    
def predict(data: List[float]):
    with open("model.pkl", "rb") as f:
        model = pickle.load(f)
    data = np.array(data).reshape(1, -1)
    prediction = model.predict(data)
    return prediction

@app.post("/predict")
def predict_route(data: List[float]):
    prediction = predict(data)
    return {"prediction": prediction}

import requests

f = open('test_data.json',) 
data = json.load(f) 

response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/predict", json=data)
print(response.json())
```

The problem arises when I try to make it work using

`uvicorn main:app --reload`

I get the following code from the cmd:

`requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: /predict (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x000002080F90E870>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))`

Can anyone help me achieve this?

Comment: If this is in the same file - there is no server running when it gets to your code. There is also generally no reason to run a http request to the same server as the one you're creating. If you want to write unit/integration tests for your endpoints, use `TestClient`: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/testing/ . If you want to test it manually, start the server in one process and make the request from another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your request is in the same file, when you run your app it goes to this line

```
response = requests.post("http://localhost:8000/predict", json=data)
```

before the server is started, resulting in your error. Remove these lines from your server code and run them separately (either via an HTTP client like Postman or curl or a separate python file/test) and it will likely work.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. Should I run 'uvicorn main:app --reload' first ? The issue is when I run the lines on a different python module, it says

INFO:     127.0.0.1:55191 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
INFO:     127.0.0.1:56247 - "POST /predict HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity

Comment: @spoolito Please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70636163/17865804) on how to submit JSON data to a FastAPI backend, as well as what `422 Unprocessable Entity` error means.